# Why only back-end - I rather like front-end - it is far more important to the topic at hand

Tags: support, april-fools, time-machine, unicorns

Why do I get shown only the backend? The frontend is far more important:

[image: The unicorn's head is missing from the left hand side of the page.]

I’m using Google Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Frontend only by F12 dev-tools:

[image: Front end of the unicorn.][image: Back end of the unicorn.]

Comment: I get both front and back-end for that unicorn. Maybe you need a minimum score in either JS or CSS to get the front-end?

Comment: Interesting theory, @yivi, since I don't see the front of the unicorn, either.

Comment: You see? That's what you get from being full-stack! Whole unicorns!

Comment: Yeah - but the post is clearly about `Front-end` so I still think it is a bug ... still trying to find out how to flag the arse for NAA

Comment: Oh wait... I don't think @yivi is actually correct. I think it has to do with the user preference for hiding the left sidebar. I have mine hidden, and I suspect Patrick does, too. When I click the hamburger menu, and what would be the left navigation sidebar drops down as a menu, the unicorn head shows up as well. It looks like they've attached the front half of the unicorn body to the side navigation well, instead of to the center post frame.

Comment: @Cody, for the record, I was just kidding. Tested it with an anonymous user and got the full-pony.

Comment: @CodyGray wow - neat spot - youre right. So only a minor bug.

Comment: i've only just found the settings for hiding the sidebar, can we has unicorns to continue testing please? oh and the sparkles back too for soothing them after terrible ordeal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So frontend guys have screwed entire project. See how broken it is:
[image: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA]
Poor unicorn turned into pieces because of them!
Somebody full-stacked should go and fix it.