# Announcing the Stack Overflow Time Machine

Tags: discussion, announcement, april-fools, time-machine

Over the years, users have told us that Stack Overflow is an indispensable tool for coders all around the world. Programmers know that when they get a Stack Overflow search result, it's likely the search is over. Following that link almost always gets a step closer to understanding whatever programming problem they face. Failing that, they can ask some of the world's most helpful and skilled developers directly. It’s hard to imagine what it was like to write code before Stack Overflow was created just over a decade ago in 2008.

If you weren't programming in the BSO (Before Stack Overflow) era, you don't know what a golden age we live in. It's not that the information wasn't available at all, but rather it was difficult to make the right connections:

[image: Who were you DenverCoder9?]

In those days programmers used a variety of incantations such as [AltaVista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltaVista), [WebCrawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebCrawler), [ICQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICQ), [Gopher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopher_(protocol)), [IRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat), [LISTSERV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LISTSERV), [Usenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet), [man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) and even [O'Reilly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_O%27Reilly) to summon answers. How many times did I come to work early in order to borrow a copy of [*UNIX in a Nutshell*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565920015) from a possessive co-worker? (Yes, Jim, I knew you didn't have those shell commands memorized. I saw you furtively flipping through that book when you didn't think anyone was watching.) Oh how I revelled when I drove home from the university bookstore with the student edition of [Borland C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_C%2B%2B) and its glorious manuals! Now *I* had the knowledge!

Helping people wasn't paradise back then either. Answer once in one forum only to see the same question in another a little later. (Probably from the same asker since you could never be sure where the best place to ask was.) Compiling a FAQ might have helped people, but nobody says "I loved the FAQ! It solved my problem." Instead, they are all like "I read the FAQ, but it didn't help." Or they don't read the FAQ and just ask their frequently asked question. Nobody upvoted the FAQ.

It seems a shame that it took two decades from the [invention of the Web](https://home.cern/science/computing/birth-web/short-history-web) before a fully-featured, public Q&A engine was built. Just think of all the time (and trees) we could all have saved by having easy access to [canonical library of answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/).  In an effort to (retroactively) make the world a better place, we're cutting that dark time in half. We’re proud to announce a new Time Machine feature that lets you experience Stack Overflow when it *should* have been around: not 2008, but 1998.

[image: Y2K baby!]

As you enjoy surfing the site, let us know in the answers below if you spot any questions that *could* have been answered in 1998 when we had:

- JavaScript but not jQuery
- C++ but not Boost
- Ruby but not Rails
- Java but not Eclipse
- C but not C#
- Python but not Django
- Visual Studio but not .NET

And if you spot any bugs, let us know what version of Netscape Navigator you are on and we'll get our webmaster on it right away. (Sorry, but we don't yet support Communicator you trailblazers.)

Comment: Appropriately, I got confused about the time to post this. It's been April 1 for several hours in [Tonga and Kiritimati (Christmas Island)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Year%27s_Eve)

Comment: Do you support NCSA Mosaic?

Comment: What, no visitor counters or little image badges saying the site is best viewed in Netscape or Internet Explorer? Edit: Gah! I found the Netscape badge. Well done.

Comment: First I thought my browser was hacked but second late it is 1. april fool

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard It’s “under construction”.

Comment: @j08691 I’m missing the “web ring”. :-/

Comment: i hope this wasnt your new CEOs idea

Comment: @Ctznkane525 We’ll have to see if it will be. If not, that’s quite a paradox.

Comment: awsome awesomeness is awesome

Comment: "python but not django" - heaven!

Comment: why do this? pointless.

Comment: This needs more tables, and less placeholders :-)

Comment: How do I get Trumpet Winsock installed again?

Comment: BTW @JonEricson, this makes the site almost unusable on Edge FYI (too many sparkles, huge flickers on scroll)

Comment: Comic sans?? Anything but comic sans!

Comment: I Hate thi chnage, hope april 1st Joke. look kind of hacked Stack :D

Comment: @j08691 There's a separate visitor counter (with a Matrixy color scheme) in the upper right corner of every question page.

Comment: Oh that Times New Roman is just... brutal.

Comment: I really miss snow-effect here, but hey, winter's already finished

Comment: Maybe throw in some marching ants?

Comment: I feel its more like april fools prank. What do you guys think??

Comment: @SauravPanda but of course...

Comment: Not enough red circles

Comment: @paul23 Also, Ruby but not Rails, heaven!

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd Yes of course it's an April Fool's joke. What else would it be?

Comment: Could have disabled the right click.

Comment: Time to play! '); DROP TABLE Users;--

Comment: Wikipedia says that Experts Exchange started up in 1996.

Comment: Doesn't xkcd require attribution?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Did I not? From what I can tell Randall Munroe just asks for [link back to xkcd.com](https://xkcd.com/license.html).

Comment: I just love the "Not Found" Image thumbnails for featured posts.

Comment: Am sorry to report that it's not cross browser compatible, there are major issues on IE5.5 and IE6.

Comment: I have a question, In the screen pic that you attached, on the right hand side, there is an opening for "Cryptocurrency Software Engineer" What does that mean?

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib: I suspect it's a glitch in [_The Matrix_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0133093/). (When you hear that phrase again next year, remember this advice: "Don't watch the sequels!")

Comment: This is just a joke, isn't it ?

Comment: @Tommy: I don't know. Are you laughing?

Comment: @JonEricson: Walk on air

Comment: The `border: 5px groove` around answers is just a black box; give it 10px and a color like `teal` and it really pops.

Comment: Borland C++?  I tried to learn Macintosh programming with Borland Pascal and the old "Inside Macintosh" manuals.  (I failed)  Thank you Chris Lattner for Swift!

Comment: I came for the help and stayed for the star cursor. I'd actually leave it on this skin if it wasn't for comic sans! Oh, and there's no blinking text, so not quite full 90's.

Comment: @JonEricson Hmm... What is "The Matrix" that you talk of? Hope you aren't referring to "The Arrays"? And why do you link to a 404 on a movie website?

Comment: Where is the unicorn? I want it back :)

Comment: @Vega Its still there, you might want to scroll top and then zoom out a little bit and you will see his rear on the right side. Thank me later.

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib, it doesn't work. yesterday, I first lost its head and then the 'second half' ;) Tried zoom in and out, mobile view, etc ... Thank you now anyway ;) P.S. I dont't havit in either of three browsers

Comment: This made my day, and it just started! Also, had to wake up a friend just so he could look at this unicorny masterpiece (it's midnight here). Totally worth it!

Comment: I'm disappointed there's no blink tag.

Comment: This website is too responsive for the 90s.  It should be optimized for 640x480 resolution.

Comment: I thought it was SO birthday or something, kinda like google doodle celebrations. Good to see fun sprinkled during mundane Mondays :)

Comment: I found this website on the third page of an altavista search!  Only two and a half pages of porn to wade through.  An all time record!

Comment: i hope this wasnt your new CEOs idea

Comment: @JagdishChaudhary Did you just copy-paste [Ctznkane525’s comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382111/4642212#comment683429_382111)?

Comment: What should we do with all those joke questions like [Should Stackoverflow now only support IE 6 and below and/or netscape?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382169/4642212), [New blogger wants customizable UI , which is better Geocities or Tripod?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382171/4642212), [Why is the new website design not using tables for alignmnet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382193/4642212)? Most of them are currently being downvoted and deleted, sometimes even “misinterpreted” as off-topic. Should they be?

Comment: @Xufox: My criteria for off-topic meta questions based on the April Fools stunt is: Is the question funny. I don't find those particularly funny.

Comment: My favourite part of the whole thing: "Proudly built in Notepad". Painfully accurate.

Comment: Why didn't the MIDI autoplay?  CompuServe said the MIDI would play.

Comment: Ah finally links all look like.. links, old man like me isn't lost anymore!

Comment: Is this post available as a hypercard stack?

Comment: I'm lovin' it :-D <3 <3

Comment: i think image in question is also April Fool post, Bcoz 5 people answered and 2 people commented but, image shows viewed 1 time. how is it possible?

Comment: I was trying emulate this awesome design in FrontPage but my Visual Source Safe got corrupted: `The file "d:\vss\data\O\ORLAAAAA" appears to be corrupt.`.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is so awesome - i really love it :D

Comment: Welcome to StackOverglow !! also, I like how downvotes decrease the opacity of posts.

Comment: "In VB so it's understandable" ❤️

Comment: The hidden unicorn is by far the awesomest awesome thing on this website!

Comment: works fine in [mosaic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326036/announcing-the-stack-exchange-time-machine/326118#326118) ;)

Comment: Where is the visits counter?

Comment: Last answer is the best: just use 2 digits and let users deal with it :D

Comment: I love the retro time-machine style. Will it still be available tomorrow?

Comment: where can we save this theme?

Comment: Color combination is grea8 , First i was confused what happen with the stackoverflow than it's remine me today is 1st april

Comment: awesome!! comments are really hilarious!!!

Comment: Can anyone please share the JS/CSS used for the pointer animation?

Comment: They are on Safari instead of Netscape Navigator.

Comment: I wish I didn't have to turn it off on **every single stack**... and its meta.  You only have to hate hats once, but this one makes me keep hating it all day long.

Comment: More <blink>blinky</blink> stuff please

Comment: Fun fact: I won medals based on 90's web design.  I even constructed a frankenstein of a shopping cart site with VBScript and Classic ASP before e-commerce was a term.  Looking back at all of it now, they all looked *horrible*.

Comment: wowowwwwwwwwwww "C but not C#" wronggggg

Comment: Looks like a Santa Claus page... This seems to be a move towards creating space to have more paid advertising content on the page.

Comment: Will this be available after april fools ? I would love to continue using this.

Comment: Is there any reason I can only see it on this exact question? If I go anywhere else on meta, or to a different site, it's back to the normal, boring theme, and the time travel button disappears!

Comment: I am dissapointed to not see a real <marquee>

Comment: They got all design flows fixed, finally..

Comment: I absolutely love it! Thanks! @ramusus I agree!

Comment: I thought SO was under a defacement XD nice one!

Comment: Page counter... we need a page counter!!!

Comment: instructions unclear; keyboard stuck in tree

Comment: What happened to the guestbook?

Comment: @neverMind9: Please see: [Why does the guestbook chatbox not produce any network activity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326018/why-does-the-guestbook-chatbox-not-produce-any-network-activity)

Answer (score 544):

1.7 MB image? Are you kidding me??!!!!!!!!!

[image: Incredibly large image]

Also, how does the date say 1919? Is that a glitch?

---

[image: Signature]

Comment: I liked your Internet Explorer 6.

Comment: @rfontoura You mean IE4, right? Unless you're coming from the future; in which case, please tell me do they have flying cars yet?

Comment: IE6 was a huge improvement in the days...

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed You thought I wouldn't notice the True Color IE6 icon in the URL bar and Quick Launch tray, didn't you!  Windows 2000 + IE6 was my childhood!

Comment: @QwertyChouskie Darn it! I was actually hesitant to add this comment and indeed hoped no one would notice since 4, 5, and 6 looked very similar. I was too lazy to find an IE4 copy for my VM and you caught me LOL! Great observation though! :D

Comment: Weird, there shouldn't be 31 months in a year.

Comment: Y2K is finally getting to us.

Comment: Looked up when PNG was invented: January 10, 1996. Well I guess that passes, but not sure how popular it was.

Comment: I believe imgur was in beta back then

Comment: that's coz it's Best Viewed in Netscape NOW! 3.0

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed in 20 years we won't have flying cars, but IE will be even slower.

Comment: stack team Are you going to crash that kid computer with 1.7 MB image LOL

Comment: Please don't use PNG, it was patented in 1985!

Comment: better than the regular stackoverflow design

Comment: @QwertyChouskie Windows 2000 + IE6 was my *update!* Actually, I'm not passionate about most of the later changes to Windows -- OK, the faster boot times are nice.

Comment: What happened to scrolling status bar???  You know, the one where Netscape showed where link is pointing to, but you could override in JavaScript? :P

Comment: @RickyA IE6 was also a compatibility nightmare. Almost made me want to switch to Netscape...

Comment: @NH. Not back in the days. It was actually great when it first came out. They just didn't release a new version until SIX YEARS LATER (which felt like an eternity). IE6 had become very obsolete in terms of design and compatibility; they finally adopted the tabbed design in IE7 (which was still a PITA but that's a story for another time).

Comment: *Also, how does the date say 1919? Is that a glitch?* It's a Y2K problem.

Comment: who remembers `document.all`

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, Unless I'm wrong, we'll only have flying cars in 2015.

Comment: please, get back the old layout or an option for us to active this

Comment: @RafaelFontoura They used to say "by the year 2000", if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @RBoschini [There you go](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382111/announcing-the-stack-overflow-time-machine/382139?noredirect=1#comment683625_382161).

Comment: Very very very cool!!!!!

Comment: The time machine's gone now :-( I miss it already.

Answer (score 309):

This page took half an hour to download although I have a fast 14.4kbps modem connection.

And to actually answer: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit) and [this is actually entertaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825055/what-does-the-c-operator-do)

Comment: aw the sound of dial-up...

Comment: At least in 1998 you had the web, in 1988 you had to hope you could catch another programmer online in chat on a bbs and maybe they had some insight into the programming problem you were working on, or hope there was a forum thread available on the subject.

Comment: Someone from the future (using time machine) told them to do so.

Comment: @KevinCook Or worse. Summer of 1992, between high school and college, I took a summer job doing in-house development for a business graphics firm. They produced slides and prints from user PowerPoint, Word, PageMaker, etc. files (a rarity at the time), so the PostScript print jobs required some pretty heavy preprocessing on their way to the slide printers. As a result, I once spent 45 minutes on hold @ Microsoft Dev Support Hotline's C++ queue, a behemoth operation which featured a live DJ to pitch products & announce hold queue lengths and wait times, drive-time radio style, in between songs.

Comment: Take a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Well, html has been so fscked up in the browser wars, that no one in its sane mind tries to parse it, with regex or otherwise. Oh, good old times when we were using gopher by connecting on an X.25 line to the terminal server of a VAX, going to another IP-connected VAX on BITNET, and using telnet from there...

Comment: @ÁrpádMagosányi You have a funny definition of the "good" old times. (When replying to this message, please copy me via UUCP at `mintaka!ogicse!uwm.edu!rpi!vm.ecs.rpi.edu!danaf`, as I am not subscribed to the list.)

Answer (score 161):

I don't know how they did it, but this looks fine **both** on 1024x768 and 800x600!

And without using a single table!

Comment: I think they used Frontpage Express, awsome tool to create webpages with sound, animation and DHTML

Comment: If you can afford it, Dreamweaver is the my go to choice.

Comment: I use both depending on my needs.

Comment: Wow, I must check out Frontpage Express, although it's hard to justify upgrading from the internet's most versatile HTML editor - http://www.notepad.org/

Answer (score 141):

I think you should follow current design trends and use the amazing `<blink>` tag more often.

Other than that the design is great, in particular the glossy gradient text that looks so much realistic thanks to the backdrop shadow.

PS: Comic Sans MS adds a sweet human touch to the overall reading experience.

Comment: Unicorns I can take. Trails coming off my mouse cursor I can stand. But *comic sans*? My eyes are bleeding!

Comment: The root cause of `epilepsy` busted!

Comment: A webpage can't be totally wrong, if you have at least one "unter construction" image or text. So this site is great already, even without extra blink.

Comment: [For anybody wondering about the out-of-universe reason for the absence of <blink>.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555592/2127008)

Comment: @rsjaffe Looks like a Santa Claus page... This seems to be a move towards creating space to have more paid advertising content on the page.

Comment: A slap in the face also adds a human touch...And I'd take that over Comic Sans any day!  I hate how my comment about how I hate Comic Sans is displayed in Comic Sans.

Comment: What it really needs is an embedded midi audio file

Comment: `<marquee>` is a decent place to experiment with `<blink>`.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu and I can't see the Comic Sans :( not sure if it's Ubuntu or just me ... Seen the Comic Sans on my colleagues PCs though :)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft The site specifically stated it was best viewed in Netscape, so `<blink>` should have still been included for those using the correct browser.

Answer (score 125):

Thank you for taking into account timezones!

As an Australian, I was pleasantly surprised to wake up this morning to this masterpiece of web design without having to suffer the agony of waiting for the Earth to rotate to such a point that our local star had line of sight to the landmass commonly known as the continental United States of America, as so often happens.

Comment: No problem! (Well, it does make your problem ours since people assume _we messed up_. 8-)

Comment: What's worse than this is waking up tomorrow and then seeing all the jokes, cause I forget then since the date is April 2nd, so it's refreshing to see the joke on the intended day! Don't worry about the rest of the world Jon, they're a bit upside down.

Answer (score 107):

Just installed Windows 98 but not able to launch 3D pinball.

Comment: It's all about minesweeper baby.

Comment: probably missing ActiveX

Comment: @Stephen hand-eye coordination is the future of gaming; I'm sure of it!

Comment: For anyone interested, [this link](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/windows-7-3d-pinball-space-cadet-game/) has instructions for how to download 3D Pinball Space Cadet Game on your computer - I've got it on mine as it's as good as I can ever remember.

Comment: @WilliamJones :O thank you for that link, you answered something i never thought of asking, but inconsciently been dreaming of! Tonight'll be pizza and game night :P

Comment: @Kaddath Enjoy!

Comment: @Kaddath Fun fact: 3D Pinball Space Cadet runs better on Linux via Wine that it does on Windows 8.1.  It has some stutters on modern Windows that can really mess up a well-timed shot, but Wine doesn't have the issue. :)

Comment: @WilliamJones see above comment

Comment: @QwertyChouskie I don't know how you would go about acquiring information, but I'm proud of you for doing so.

Comment: @WilliamJones I have the info because I play it on my laptop and it would stutter on Windows 8 but run pretty nicely on Wine, on the same hardware.  Of course, different hardware may behave differently.

Comment: @MichaelSchinis - Yeah, and DirectX 3

Answer (score 85):

I'm editing it!

[image]

Comment: LMAO!!! MS WORD!!!

Comment: Nice profile pic

Comment: <BLINK> CLIPPY! </BLINK>

Comment: wow , you made my day , its  traveling back to 90's

Comment: RIP! Clippy aka Office Assistant aka MS Assistant. You will not be missed!!

Comment: awe, the paper clip.  for some reason I remember him as being very rude and vulgar.... maybe that's just what i imagined based on the "help" he gave.

Comment: Did the MS paper click ever have sound support? I'm always wondering what his voice would sound like.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to edit a StackExchange webpage.  Would you like help with that?  * Make a header.  * Make an envelope.  * Rerun the StackExchange Webpage Wizard.

Comment: @cowlinator like this clippy? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions/358027#

Comment: It looks like you've posted something on Stack Overflow.  Would you like some help?

Comment: Nah. It says "read only" in the title.

Answer (score 70):

I hope you will tell us tomorrow if more questions were downvoted than usual.

Comment: Why would a April fool's joke by the company behind Stack Overflow cause people to downvote regular users' questions? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Many downvoters vote down based on their current mood rather than on the objective quality of the post.

Comment: @MrLister -1 Nobody ever does that! (On an unrelated note, my mother just died)

Comment: @seadoggie01 Poor taste... leave yer mum alone pls ;(

Comment: @seadoggie01 maybe *she* did, and as you just cursed her, so she died because of it ?

Comment: I am interested to look at activity during this natural experiment. My guess is everything will go up a tiny bit due to the [novelty effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novelty_effect). But it would be interesting if voting direction were influenced somehow. Most all the data will be available on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Actually, the first thing I noticed was that I felt way less compelled to fix bad questions (especially for bad spelling/grammar and bad formatting), probably due to the fact that in this canvas they don't look out of place at all.

Comment: @seadoggie01 very very poor taste, you will understand when it realy happens

Comment: [Why did Google Search Trends for Stack Overflow spike in April 2019?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393803/3404097)

Answer (score 64):

Help  . I have been playing on my parents' Windows 95 computer and I am getting errors now  . Can you help me  ???????????????????????????????

[image]

Comment: It's aint Windows 95, it says Millenium Edition in the background. Another visitor from the future.

Comment: No problem - press [Windows] + [R], then enter "format c:" in the prompt, that will fix it ;)

Comment: Millenium Edition could go further.. I still remember the error: "Unknown has caused an error in Unknown. Unknown will now close."

Comment: @StefanSteiger I tried that but it doesn't work, although my icons disappeared what to do now?

Comment: @window.document: Simple: You perform a restart ;)

Comment: Millenium Edition.. Just push ctrl+alt+delete twice. Fun thing to do to my class mates in 2001.

Comment: Windows 95 also didn't have the gradient on the title bars. They were either solid blue or solid grey.

Comment: Hellooo again  . It is year 2000 and I am 5 years old  . Can you tell me more ????????????????

Answer (score 62):

What I have found in page source. 
[image]

Answer (score 50):

Just tried it on my i486DX with dial-up and Mosaic-browser and it looks as expected. The only downside was that I had to wait for 27 minutes for the page to load.. ;)

[image]

Comment: including the banner? you scrolled past it.

Comment: It's a shop. There is no compatible cypher suite between Mosiac and the cert.

Comment: @Joshua Well spotted, other than that you can identify the `shop` also on the font-type and size in the url-bar and the window-header as well as on the res ;)

Answer (score 47):

This reminded me of some pages by Henning Thielemann I read back in 2001 when I was 19. 
They're still ONLINE !

They forgot to add a few random BS e-mail addresses generated with markov-chains to feed the spam-miners.

Here for general amusement

- [C-Hater](http://www.henning-thielemann.de/CHater.html)
- [Scripting & Matlab hater](http://www.henning-thielemann.de/ScriptingHater.html)
- [Denglish for beginners](http://www.henning-thielemann.de/Dictionary.html)
- [Dictionary of NewSpeak vs. OldSpeak](http://www.henning-thielemann.de/Reform.html)
- [Full contents](http://www.henning-thielemann.de/Contents.html)

Sorry if it's in German, you'll just need to take the time-machine back into 2019 and use google-translate on the links ;)

[image: Best Viewed with EYES]

[image: Made on AMIGA!]

[image: Internet Explorer TrollFace]

Comment: Thank you, that is Quality stuff.

Comment: best viewed with eyes lol (my sensitivity stopped me from making a braille joke... i should have been born a flea (one piece anime reference) >_>)

Comment: Love the Made on Amiga! ❤️I learned web dev on my A1200 in 1997!

Comment: Yay! I'm the original creator of that troll face EI logo! I made it when they first launched the gen 1 surface tablet and it crashed live lol.

Comment: @Lei-Lonnie: Ya have it as SVG somewhere ?

Answer (score 44):

Guyz I just bought this personal computing machine, can we also add a feature for **<<< BACKGROUND MUSIC >>>** for this forum? also I have a few family pics that I wanted to show you folks, can anyone please upload the drivers for apple flatbed scanner? Thanks for your help.

Please help! [image]

Comment: Seizure alert..

Comment: I thought the whole point of 90s Design language was to prevent emotionally vulnerable people from using cutting edge technology.

Answer (score 34):

How do I get rid of the padding in a table? My logo and navigation have a weird space between them. I've searched and searched but all I get is f*$%ing Experts Exchange links.

Comment: Just scroll down :D

Comment: Insert a new column with a 1 pixel gif between the logo and the navigation, e.g., `<td><img src="spacer.gif" width="1"></td>`. Add me on ICQ if you need help!

Comment: Too bad you will have to wait for World Wide Web Consortium to release the new CSS v2 this may, using that it will be pretty simple, just add float left to everything, and it will just magically just fix everything. Its bleeding edge technology. The future is now old man.

Comment: Remove ALL characters between /> and <.

Comment: Try using www.metacrawler.com instead of www.altavista.com. I find their results are better.

Answer (score 34):

how do run macro i recorded need progremer help please!!!!

Comment: Try Alt+F4, it worked for me

Comment: Haha, this is funny :o)

Answer (score 33):

Please fix the scrolling text, it is not created by using `marquee` tag.

Comment: Yes and the page is styled with css not table.

Comment: Yes, please. I was very dissapointed to not see the standard <marquee> tag

Comment: Haha, my first thought. Checked the source and was disappoint.

Answer (score 31):

Those colored snowflakes lag on my Netscape communicator (I'm a Voodoo 3 user). The page freezes before the animation ends. Now I have to use the keyboard only to avoid mouse move.

Comment: I always told you kids that this mouse and trackball thing is no more than a marketing gimmick and gonna be a fad, the only real way to use a Personal Computer is using a keyboard. SMH.

Comment: Lucky you, my voodoo is only the version 2 and my 100 Mo drive is compressed to get some extra space.  Why is everything so slow ?

Answer (score 27):

I am interested to know how do they have the asterisk sprinkle when the cursor is moved.

Comment: Ironically one the oldest "DHTML" tricks!

Comment: See https://github.com/tholman/90s-cursor-effects for details.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I was born in the mid 90's, so I have no idea of how this would be implemented. Thank you for providing me this resource! Looking into it now.

Comment: @codeherk Note that the code in the repository is anachronistic.

Comment: I was wondering when that became possible myself. It was a pleasant surprise to find [this code with a copyright date of 1998](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/dhtml/article.php/3470581/So-You-Want-A-Mouse-Trail-Huh.htm#nn).

Comment: The fact that this effect has opacity fading and works on things other than a specific version of IE is also anachronistic. :)

Comment: who remembers javascript.internet.com

Answer (score 25):

I wanna run a QBasic script to play a `.wav` file through Winamp API. But I get this error:
[image]

```
A:\> Play.bas neverland.wav

Bad command or file name
```

Please help! [image]

Comment: how did you fit a wav file in your floppy drive???

Comment: Must have been a really short audio clip!

Comment: Is winamp in floppy also?

Comment: You need to add Play.bas to your PATH. Use `SET PATH=% PATH%;C:\progra~1\winamp\`

Answer (score 21):

You're missing an embedded sound file playing some 80's music. With the unicorn theme, Erasure would be appropriate...

Comment: A "shame" none of the browsers allow autoplaying audio anymore.

Comment: but ad videos. this is ok i guess.

Answer (score 21):

I like, this makes me laugh when i visit stack-overflow, it kinda makes me dizzy a little...

But looks good, it does look like some goofy '90s over painted place, but the font's look good :-) and colorful.

I like [image]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Img/april-fools-2019/fire.gif?v=a3a5393ce037))</sub>
 next to the hot network questions list :-)

Answer (score 20):

Love this annotation

[image]

Comment: Of course, the best are Amiga browsers of course- like [AWeb](http://aminet.net/package/comm/www/AWeb-3.5.09-68000), [Voyager](http://aminet.net/package/comm/www/Voyager) or best of the best - [IBrowse](https://www.ibrowse-dev.net).
Have fun :)

Answer (score 19):

I'm just trying to figure out how you guys created this entire page without using a single <FONT> tag.

Answer (score 15):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1003841/52738) could have really helped me in 1987. I *would* ask you to rewind the time machine another decade, but that would put us before the creation of the Web itself, and God only knows what sort of anti-causal horror that might bring about.

Answer (score 13):

Please help. I am using DSL and the webpage isn't running. Currently using IE 6 on Windows 98.

Comment: DSL ....IE6....Win 98 .....cool!! Wish I had it so good ! Win 95 , AOL and dial up modem user here . *"You got Mail"*

Comment: YOU HAVE DSL!? Here I am on crappy dialup with internet boost that splits every request over 5 requests for maximum speed... and you have DSL. Your parents must be millionaires

Answer (score 12):

I mean, this is not a feature request but like ... can temporarily suspended user (like those suspended for 20 years) wind back the time machine and ask questions or give answers on the site before they get banned or after their suspension get lifted. Is it possible?

Answer (score 12):

I'm trying to switch to suggested browser for a better experience. But the browser complains to me that "no common encryption algorithms". How can I fix this. Please help! :)

Answer (score 10):

Where is the "tn tn" sound? 90's website is incomplete with the welcome music.

Answer (score 9):

## Wanted

A Unicorn has gone missing. Please return if found!

[image: missing unicorn]

Jokes aside, why is the head missing? I've disabled the left bar, maybe thats why?

Comment: Yes, the head depends on the left bar. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382074/why-only-back-end-i-rather-like-front-end-it-is-far-more-important-to-the-to

Comment: But what's happened to 'Corny's' back leg?  It seems to have gone walkabouts by itself!

Comment: How did you disable it by the way?

Answer (score 9):

And where are all the animated gifs?

Comment: I think your time machine is broken! You're spinning around in the time tunnel! This is a topic that we returned to after 25 years. With the advent of today's messengers and social networks ((:

Answer (score 8):

Kind of pedantic, but `#tm-scroll` could use a `will-change: transform`.

Visually authentically awful though.

Answer (score 8):

Tbh, wouldn't mind this as an option. The work's already been done

Comment: I'm glad you like it! Unfortunately, half (or more) of developing a feature is maintenance. We've failed to recall that truth far too many times.

Comment: Ah, I guess usually with my html projects, I don't change the structure very much, so the CSS stays consistent

Comment: Oh. I forgot to point you at [this excellent answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/326045/1438).

Comment: @trainboy2019 Meh, I don't still trust CSS, I just like to stick to plain HTML!! it keeps the user experience fluid. And "Everything" can be achieved using html then why complicate things.

Answer (score 7):

> In those days programmers used a variety of incantations such as
>   AltaVista, WebCrawler, ICQ, Gopher, IRC, LISTSERV, Usenet, man and
>   even O'Reilly to summon answers.

I started my degree as the Internet was appearing.

My best resources were the library (books & Dr. Dobb's magazines) or to buy books from University book shop. In later years Compuserve was also helpful - sometimes :)

Comment: ...and Archie and Veronica help me a lot during college.  Funny you should mention Dr. Dobb's, I also learned a lot just from flipping through the ads.

Answer (score 7):

RIP Perl, we loved you well. Thanks for all your help with those big genomes we didn't know how to evaluate.

Comment: I'll be honest, I wanted to include nothing but Perl references in the announcement, but I didn't want it to be that sad. I miss Perl.

Comment: I work in a microbiology lab. Perl is, sadly, alive and well for me...

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not dead.

Comment: You guys would be amazed by the quantity of software that still uses perl. Perl isn't dead,  just dormant.

Comment: What's Perl?............

Answer (score 6):

This made me happy. Fantastic. Tugged on all the right heartstrings.

Answer (score 6):

I heard two C++ experts talking about some new feature being added to C++9x.
They were calling it templates! What exactly are templates and how to use them?

Comment: templates are a proposed magic to replace #define T int ... #include "stack.h" ... #undef T   ... stack(int) stack;  stack.push_back(3); if (stack.overflow()) exit(1);  Replace with basically the same thing but no #define T.  Seems like a wasteful language feature to me.

Answer (score 6):

This is yet another proof, that developer's working time is 90% "self education". [read leisure time]

Answer (score 6):

I hope this wasnt your new CEOs idea,it's easy to switch with theme by click the clock icon to switch to the original theme.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

I want to remove a Minesweeper from my son's computer. but he hid the game on another disk. Help me find

Comment: It's on A:. But I do't know which floppy.

Comment: Sorry, but this just isn't a good enough joke. If this had have been more legitimate, then we wouldn't be able to see a `~` in the command line prompt.  :o/   ;o)

Answer (score 5):

Anyone who marked-up in the 90s will realise that there's a distinct problem with SOs rendition of a 90s site - it's just too damned clean!  It really does need to have attributes used in place of CSS.  The longer you can make your inline styles, and the more stomach curdling you can make the graphics, the better.

Comment: This is a fair point! I look at this and think.. Nope, not ugly enough. I can find things and stand to scroll down...

Answer (score 5):

What awards did stackoverflow win and where are the badges? ^^

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately (for the Dutchies) we have http://www.leejoo.nl/, an incredible site with lots of tips and tricks for webdevelopers. Such as [shortkeys for Frontpage 2000](http://www.leejoo.nl/tips-tricks/tips-tricks.htm#Sneltoetsen%20voor%20Frontpage%202000), [a Frame Generator](http://www.leejoo.nl/generatoren/framegen/frames_generator1.htm), [A resolution tester](http://www.leejoo.nl/tips-tricks/tips-tricks.htm#De%20Resolutie%20Tester) and much more!!

*Unfortunately... this website isn't an April Fool, it's a real website that tries to help people building their website...*

Comment: Oh! That's awful! They even use tables to lay out their mark-up... :o(

Comment: Oh wow thanks, I had trouble finding a nice fader scroller java-applet! This website helped me.

Answer (score 4):

Please make a browser add-on where I can keep this 1990's website layout!
Much more colourful and favourable than the new world of *modern* 2D monotone flat iOS7-style design! I really enjoy this early web nostalgia. Thank you!

I also like the colourful mouse cursor snowflake effect. **Brilliant.**

But whose genius idea was it? I really like it. It is very creative.

Comment: [Will there be an option to permanently keep this year's April Fools design active?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326037/289905).

Answer (score 3):

Well, made my day. Didn't have any experience about the websites of 90s. And, so lazy I am that I never tried to find one also till now.

Answer (score 2):

Can we reverse engineer the floppy disks to unlock my 28.8 to 56k modem? I would really enjoy loading this site twice faster.

Answer (score -1):

Today we are enjoing a april fool time machine theme and some laughter question answer, Only because of **Joel Spolsky**, **Jeff Atwood**. **Hats off sirs**.

[image]

**Joel Spolsky** and **Jeff Atwood** sir really thank you sir.

Answer (score -2):

I'm recently resurrecting a project I started in 1997 when I was in high school. It was a music calendar and message board hacked together from Perl scripts from Matt's Script Archive. Later converted to PHP by 2001 before handing the project off to others who then let the domain name expire, which I recently was able to get back when it went up for auction on GoDaddy. I feel like I own some sort of internet artifact: a 20+ year old domain name.

As an aside... anyone remember you had to edit text files and email them back and forth to manage domains with the registrar prior to SSL being supported? Good stuff.

Comment: It still lives! https://www.scriptarchive.com/

Answer (score -2):

Found a mis located tip box while visiting the site on Redmi 5A and Vivo V5s:
Sorry for the text in my tooltip, I wanted to write: ***It should point here.***
[image: Mis located tooltip]

Comment: You're saying the tooltip should go up out of the page and over browser chrome? That's nigh-impossible, for the extremely good security reason that it would allow pages to fake browser UI much more smoothly.

Comment: @NathanTuggy The issue is the horizontal alignment. The arrow of the tooltip isn’t centered underneath the clock icon in the responsive view at the breakpoint of 640px width and less.

Comment: I did that to point out. Else it would overlap the text.

Answer (score -13):

> in 1998 when we had
>
> - JavaScript but not jQuery
> - C++ but not Boost
> - Ruby but not Rails
> - Java but not Eclipse
> - C but not C#
> - Python but not Django
> - Visual Studio but not .NET

In 2019, C++ still has Boost, Ruby still has Rails, Java still has Eclipse, C# is still around, Python still has Django, Visual Studio sill has .NET.

Let's face it, no one is using jQuery any more.

How did we end up in a situation when JavaScript is the only widely used language that is still evolving?

To answer the question: here's one which was asked in 2010, could well have been asked in 1998, and has an open bounty as of today: [How do you get a string to a character array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-do-you-get-a-string-to-a-character-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Oh I wish nobody used jQuery anymore. I wish it was true.

Comment: That may be so, but it's important to [honor ancient wisdom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/1438).

Comment: Sorry? Since when does no one use jQuery any more? It's still incredibly widely used. I'm confused by this statement.

Comment: Seriously? Eclipse?

Comment: Evolution of JavaScript frameworks will slow down when the community sticks with one long enough to reach critical mass.

Comment: _"no one is using jQuery any more"_ That statement is so incorrect it's as if it's a nineties prediction about the state of jQuery in 2010.