# Why is the new website design not using tables for alignment?

Tags: feature-request, april-fools, time-machine

It's the 1990s, Tables are all the rage for alignment control. Yet I see a disturbing lack of tables in use. This new-fangled CSS is just a fad and will never work, no good programmer will want to externalize their design and logic from the webpage.

How can this website ever make a nice professional-looking website without using Tables?

I am going back to Ask Jeeves to get my questions answered.

Comment: It's an important speed optimization. You see, the browser has to wait until all tables content has been loaded before it can start doing the layout. Not all of our users have upgraded to 33.6 Kbps modems, so we need to optimize loading time as much as possible.

Comment: Nobody ever needs more than 9600 baud.

Comment: CSS is buggy unusable mess. IF IE 5 comes out with CSS support, I will poop and then eat my shorts.

Comment: Umm...IE 4 had pretty complete support for basic CSS. Bon appetit?

Comment: @CodyGray So you're telling me that 20 years from now, we will all still be OK with content that bounces all over the place until everything is loaded?  As if!  That's what will happen if elements change size as things are loaded asynchronously.

Comment: It continues to amaze me what people will put up with, @rgettman. [Speaking of things bouncing around all over the place in IE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381685/366904)...