# Why are Stack Overflow questions receiving so many views lately?

Tags: discussion, questions, views

I am a C++ user. On average, all questions here have something like 40 views after an hour. A good question might even get 50 views within only 15 minutes. Or so it has been the last months. However, today I saw **a lot** of traffic going on.

Here you can see a very tech-specific post that received **191** views after just **1 minute**:

[image: a very "Android C++ Buffer" question]

After 4 minutes the growth declined leaving the viewed pages count at 300 views. And this is not an exception, many more posts (also on other tags) seem to receive hundreds of views within the first minutes. Here are the newest questions from the [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) page:

[image: Java newest questions displaying 4 new questions where 2 have over 300 views]

While this rapid growth doesn't affect all questions it is still quite a change.

I could see 2 reasons:

- Maybe because a lot of people are online? After all, it's the first April and their [time machine/back to the future](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382111/announcing-the-stack-overflow-time-machine) attraction might attract a lot of people resulting in a (temporarily) increase of active users.
- Maybe they have changed their algorithms? Recently they [announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/updating-the-hot-network-questions-list-now-with-a-bit-more-network-and-a-litt?noredirect=1&lq=1) that they would update the hot network section to be **more network** and **less hot**. I could see that while modifying their internal structure they have also tweaked their activity algorithms. Could this be a reason?

Comment: Well if you tag a question both Java and C++, that will certainly attract a lot of eyeballs :)

Comment: same happening with the CSS tag even with off topic question  https://stackoverflow.com/q/55458841/8620333

Comment: Same situation: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382290/view-counter-appears-incorrect

Comment: The view counter going nuts co-incides with the April 1st joke release.  Yesterday (slow Sunday) many questions got ~70 views in a hurry.  Could be the guestbook, hmm.  If it is then it is the most effective rewrite of the dead [newnav] feature we've seen yet.  Promising.

Comment: I agree with @HansPassant. I saw lots of Twitter and Reddit posts linked to SO today because of the April Fool design.

Comment: If it's only the april fools, then the effect exceeds my expectations. As said on one of the duplicates, a question only tagged ms-access got 310 views in 6 minutes, and that's a tag with 10-20 active contributors. I don't have an alternate explanation, though.

Comment: Also why would the effect be clustered on specific questions? If people are randomly clicking on questions just to view the theme why wouldnt this be distributed more evenly? If links are shared for specific questions and gain 300 views in a few mins then why dont the views continue to grow steadily after that from the link?

Comment: The views only coming in at the start is explained easily, though. The links are probably to the main page, and you need to click a random question to see the effect. By default, that's sorted by _interesting_, which could explain some of the clustering.

Comment: 30 views on a Powershell question in 3 minutes.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460172

Comment: I noticed this same thing. A [somewhat obscure post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458963/send-azure-blob-storage-event-notifications-to-event-hubs-on-another-account) received over 200 views in the first couple seconds, and then only a few more in the following time.

Comment: same is happening on the `pandas` tag. For the past year you'd be surprised to find a question with more than 50 views after several hours. Now some are racking up 300 within 2 minutes.

Comment: I want the April Fools pagestyle back.  Could it be added as a permanent option???  It may not drive traffic so much, when it's not 4/1, but....... WHO DOESN'T LIKE UNICORNS AND RAINBOW CURSOR TRAILS? :D  (As long as it can be turned off, LOL.)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

So... I've spent a frankly embarrassing amount of time trying to figure this out today. But I think I've tracked down the culprit:

[image: that creepy unicorn that shows up bisected by the question pages today]

Yep. [This April 1st thing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382111/announcing-the-stack-overflow-time-machine?cb=1) is really driving some traffic to the homepage:

[image: a chart of homepage traffic, going sharply up starting March 31st]

<sup>*Visits to the homepage per day, sampled at 1%*</sup>

That's a *lot* of extra people loading the homepage and clicking through to questions to find some sparkles. The homepage is cached for a bit, so questions that show up there and happen to end up near the top are gonna tend to get seen more than those that happen to sort nearer to the bottom...

...So, short answer is that this is a temporary thing. Enjoy it while it lasts... And happy April 1st!

Comment: [The usual suspect](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/b7ojga/the_stackoverflow_april_fools/) (1.9 million subscribers)? Isn't the information in the REFERER [sic] field?

Comment: Need an updated graph now that the festivities are over to see that gigantic plummet :)

Comment: Stack Overflow regularly gets low views on weekends - expected behavior?

Comment: Why is the unicorn cut in half?

Comment: @pushkin There was a really unfortunate incident at the magic show last night...  Also it was split between the left and right sides of the main section.

Comment: Whats the difference between "Anonymous" and "Unregistered" in the graph?

Comment: @tkausl I'm completely guessing, but based on the low numbers and the distinction from "anonymous" I would think "unregistered" is someone who has a network profile (from other SE sites) and is logged in but does not have a StackOverflow profile.

Comment: @iBug definitly. Many developers don't work on weekends and therefore dont need SO on weekends

Comment: @XtremeBaumer You missed the second half: most developers on SO are from the  same time zone, apparently.

Comment: Moderator traffic steady at "nonexistent", I see. Explains a lot, really.

Comment: The traffic in that graph is sampled at 1%, @MikeTheLiar - so any group that small is likely to just disappear. (I probably should've mentioned that sooner, but I forgot)

Comment: @Shog9 I'm on to you, diamonds. I'm on to you.

Comment: Almost, @Paulpro - "Unregistered" is what you have when you post without creating an account. So folks who post answers on SO and just enter a name and email address but don't actually create a way to log in.

Comment: Done, @Gimby - see edit.

Comment: Someone deleted some comments but that's not listed on the [revision page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/382315/revisions).

Comment: Yeah, that'd be cool wouldn't it? Unfortunately that's not what happens to deleted comments.

Comment: @shog9 disappointing, it'd had been hilarious if the line had stayed straight and it was actually a really big miracle fluke that the site just exploded in popularity when it looked exceedingly garish.