# Why is this user no longer a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I noticed that [Samuel Liew](https://stackoverflow.com/u/584192), an *elected* moderator, here, on Stack Overflow, is... just simply no longer a moderator.

What I first saw was:

> [image: Where's the diamond?]

but I thought it was a bug and the diamond will come back to its position. I also thought that because the sidebar is cached, the diamond was removed from his profile, but not from the sidebar, yet.

And I was right. After about 5 minutes, the diamond was missing from the sidebar.

So, just wanted to ask: Did he step down? Or this is something related to [this planned maintenance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326718), possibly a bug? Samuel was a very active mod - in fact he had recently deleted some answers and handled some flags.

Comment: Ripple in the space-time continuum. It seems we're still suffering some aftershocks from the recent [time traveling experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382111/announcing-the-stack-overflow-time-machine).

Comment: On the bright side, once this is fixed, Samuel can have the pride of saying he became an SO mod _twice_ ;)

Comment: @cs95 - heh, but the second time was unelected `:=)`

Comment: \*puts on tin hat\* It's the government, man..... They're everywhere.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Let's just say that something went wrong with his account.

I've emailed him, but he's probably asleep, given the timezone. I temporarily removed his moderator status to prevent potential damage while I wait for a reply.

Answer (score 54):

Pleased to announce [Samuel Liew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew) is now back as moderator and all is well.

Comment: Do we even want to know what went wrong?

Comment: @Joshua honestly, it wasn't a big deal. It was a userscript issue. The account needed to have mod privileges removed until Sam could stop the script.

Comment: "and all is well" - in this context.  We still have to worry about global warming, Brexit, and, and, and ... what's become of that crisp bacon we had before the war? ... :-)

Comment: @StephenC oh yeh... Have you seen David Attenborough's latest series [Our Planet](https://www.ourplanet.com/en/)? It's hard to watch, but it is hopeful. We desperately need to make changes. It makes our problems on SO seem trivial.

Comment: Jeeze [Dynasties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynasties_(2018_TV_series)) was hard watching at points.

Comment: Oh, I thought *Our Planet* was an extended allegory for the problems on Stack Overflow. The plastics that trap wildlife are like the low-quality questions that trap experts. The walruses falling off the cliff are like the legitimate questions that never get answered because they're crowded out by garbage. You mean there exist problems that are larger than this web site?

Comment: I wish there was an option to tag a comment as funny.  Just upvoting is not expressive enough :-)

Comment: @StephenC you got my upvote for this lol.... but seriously - *tag as funny* should be a feature here

Comment: As a french I can annonce that Rich French will donate 200M€ to rebuild poor question that have been burn in the great curation.

Comment: "Funny" is an interesting way to describe comments of the nature that are usually marked "No longer needed" on this site... :p

Comment: So .. Samuel was about to awaken Skynet and you prevented it? Well done!

Comment: @YvetteColomb So for us who don't know very much...Samuel Liew ran a 24-hour script, which started to go haywire?

Comment: @cs95 Funny stuff is fine on Meta. Extremely funny stuff is fine on main. Pages and pages of people cracking jokes isn't fine on main; at some point, it ceases to be funny.

Comment: @StephenC I thought I was the only person left who used that expression! So nice to know I'm not alone...

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - I agree.  I didn't intend my "I wish ..."  comment to be interpreted as feature request.   Note the smiley.