# Yet another "step down as moderator" post

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-resignation

It saddens me and breaks my heart in a lot of ways to do so, so I'd like to explain **very** briefly "why".

Can't say much because I'd have to plagiarise George Stocker's [resignation notice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390427/im-resigning-as-a-stack-overflow-community-elected-moderator)  and he's  already verbalised that brilliantly.

It's been great being on this site (diamond or not)... I've had the pleasure of meeting people, some of which, I'd happily call friends.

Let's keep our best paw forward, yeah?

Comment: _Never cruel or cowardly. **Never give up**, never give in._

Comment: Jon, Though we've worked together for years, I only got to hear your voice for the first time a few months ago, and I just want to say that I am saddened that you are resigning, and that I cherished our time together as moderators, and hope you will continue to help Stack Overflow in whatever way you feel best able.  Your compassion for the community and your continued efforts to represent the community made me feel even prouder to work with you.

Comment: Very sad to see you go, Jon. I've only seen you around a few times, and haven't interacted with you much if at all, but I know how much time and effort you (and other mods) have put in here, and it is very surreal feeling to see all of you (rightfully) step away as of recently. I can't imagine SE saw all of this coming a few weeks ago.

Comment: I can't upvote this either. I hope we'll still have you around, ninja puppy :)

Comment: @Magisch I haven't forgotten the things that matter - whether you like it or not I'll still be around :)

Comment: This is so sad. Sorry to see you go. You were one of the few chat moderators. You were willing to get your hands dirty to listen to and put up with everyone's whining to understand and assess the various complicated chat situations to take the appropriate actions. Thank you for your service.

Comment: @Mysticial everythings eventual mate

Comment: not answering here, no need to add to the answers. But definitely NOT COOL

Comment: Ouch, ouch, ouch.  I could understand the previous resignations, mods that tried to apply the company directives and found them to be hopelessly unpractical.  I don't get this one.  Speak for yourself, please.  Or don't if you don't want to fight the fight, that's quite okay.  Your meta posts were always eminently sensible, caring and respectful, thank you.

Comment: Another bloody downvote Jon! dam!

Comment: Title suggestion: YASDAMP.

Comment: Not the Ninja Puppy - your one of the reasons I still come to SO! (not kidding about this and much respect is all I can say)

Comment: I hope we still see our favorite ninja puppy around in chat; we'll have scooby snacks!

Comment: *sigh* May th 4th be with you always. SO goes down an ever steeper slope now that you are done moderating. Thanks for your patience and time spent trying to make it better then it is.

Comment: Never ship on Friday, ever. Take care!

Comment: Well then... All I have to say to this is... [woof woof bark bark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MujRLvZ61jE).

Comment: Less than 12 hours to remove your diamond and George is still waiting 3 days later! Thanks for everything Jon, another dedicated and first class moderator is lost.

Comment: Oh man. All the mods who've stepped down, I respected, as I do you. But the bigger thing about you that's stuck with me most from the times we've interacted is how darn *friendly* you are. I'm not surprised by the heartbreak others are voicing; we've lost a few mods now, but it's the first time we've lost a ninja puppy.

Comment: Btw. if all the resigning moderators or users actually don't just disperse but maybe having a common destination in mind, a new shore or something, please let us others know somehow.

Comment: @DavidG I found out the scoop on that; looks like Jon met with Shog last night and wanted to convey things over voice chat; and while they were doing that Jon asked Shog to immediately remove his diamond. The normal process dumps us in a queue and as CMs are able to get to it they do.  Right now things are a bit... backed up.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Ah I see, thanks for clarifying. The next election on SO is going to be super interesting. I wonder who would nominate themselves in these circumstances.

Comment: What would make you reconsider this decision? It's very sad for us, users, to see moderators quit.

Comment: I'm just an engineer trying to answer or ask question, basically I get to see lots of hard working moderators but in a bad way when they move out. I can't get most of the conversations or answers to the post, but I can understand there is something uncomfortable ( I guess I can say ) going on for you.

Comment: Any agreement you have with the site is void once they start acting arbitrarily. You're not bound by it. Your real commitment in any case is the *community*, not to the people who happen to control the corporation at the moment. Your better move would be not to resign, but to stay in the job and provide some leadership in doing the right thing by the community until you're fired for doing the right thing by the community. Management is more than happy if mods with a conscience purge themselves.

Comment: By the way, Jon, I believe I recall that you're British, unlike (as far as I'm aware!) any of the SO mods who've stepped down so far. If you happen to be based in London, I'd be glad to buy you a pint to thank you for your service. Most likely several of the other Brits in the userbase would gladly do the same.

Comment: We really should have a "moderator-resignation" tag for these sorts of things.

Comment: This has almost gotten to the point where all these resignations could be merged into a single thread where each answer is the individual's resignation

Comment: We'll need another moderator election soon.

Comment: [Walking into the SO moderator room like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqJVa0fl01w)

Comment: Who was/were the other moderator(s) that stepped down?

Comment: @TaslimOseni https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965

Comment: Why do you think that, @jhpratt? What do you mean by “sabotage”? I expect voters will be looking for the same things in a moderator that they *always* have. My read of the community is that sentiments and values have not changed, so why would the election change? Certainly, very few community members would be casting a vote for a candidate that they perceive is nothing more than a deputy (shill?) of Stack Overflow, Inc., but I don’t think that’s anything new. Mods have always been elected as representatives of the community, not the company. That isn’t a bad thing, and certainly not sabotage.

Comment: Sorry to hear this Jon, but glad you are taking a principled stand, 100% behind you. Hope to be able to buy/have some beers with you one day (once I am living in the UK again).

Comment: It was a pleasure working with you, Jon. I'm sad that so many of us have had to take this step.

Comment: Thank you for your service @JonClements and for always being there and looking to help and improve things - it has been a pleasure, see you around!

Comment: Hi @JonClements, I read that you are leaving. For the time on SO, your guidance and your patience that helped many of us technically but more of all, to feel welcome in the python community, thank you although this thank you seems to me , very minor.

Man, you will be missed. 

Again, if we meet one day, beers are on me.

Comment: You literally changed lives matey -- I know you did because you did mine and I'm not exaggerating here!  Although that happened years before you became a moderator.  You had a fantastic influence on the culture of the communities we've both been part of.  You never had to _pull rank_ because your example, your attitude and patience were enough and silently changed the mentality of others.  Of course your resignation will change none of these, I know you will remain the same amazing _influencer_, but from SO's perspective it is an immeasurable loss.  All the best, Your R.A.B.B.I.T.'s designer.

Comment: Step down as a moderator? Or step down as a moderator *and* "step down" as an (active) user? *"It's been great being on this site (diamond or not)..."* suggests the latter.

Comment: Just the former @PeterMortensen

Comment: never gonna give you up never gonna let you down never gonna run around and hurt you. That's the main thing that came to my head when reading your bio. Best of luck mate.

Comment: Sorry I didn't write earlier, it's getting difficult to compose goodbye messages to so many people I respect. You engaged with chat in a way that few moderators had before, and that was both an incredible help and a great template for the rest of us. I learned a ton from our conversations and from the unique perspective you often contributed. I really enjoyed working together with you. As I've said for others, you did a lot of good here and can be proud of your time as moderator.

Comment: It is such a shame that these issues still make elected moderators leave the community... I wish somebody could give more details of what happens behind the scene

Comment: I think a new community will need to be created.

Comment: @JonClements thank you tremendous efforts. Moderation cannot be easy. It almost looks to be Sisyphean!

Answer (score 169):

Jon, I know you've been considering this for some time, but it still saddens me to say goodbye. I hope we'll still see each other around, even if it won't be in The Blue Room.

You carved out a crucial niche in the team, identifying overlooked and under-served areas like chat moderation that desperately needed a firm and sympathetic guiding hand. You've stood out as patient and kind, always willing to listen or contribute suggestions.

You badgered me incessantly about flag and kick stats. Now who will do that? Am I going to have to cave and build actual *tools* for this? *shudders*

Best wishes in your travels; may your path be smooth and your direction clear. And thank you, for everything.

Comment: Ditto Josh. I'd like to have done more over time, but c'est la vie... it's been an absolute pleasure.

Comment: @JonClements I already miss you from my own absence, now this is even worse :'(

Comment: Don’t worry, I’ll find something to badger you about.

Comment: All this time and I never knew Shog was called Josh, I had assumed you were the 9th child and your parents were just lazy namers!

Comment: "Am I going to have to cave and build actual tools for this?" no, **Stack Exchange Inc** should be building tools for that.

Comment: @Ian Psst... Shog9 works for Stack Exchange, Inc. And since companies are abstract entities who can't actually do things, they cheat by employing people to do things for them.

Comment: "Am I going to have to cave and build actual tools for this?" - Do you mean build the tools that Jon was asking for or build chatbots to _ask_ you to build the tools? Sadly, the chatbots may be a lot easier.

Comment: Both? Was kind of a joke at my own expense, since I won't have Jon to remind me to watch these things @andrew :-/

Answer (score 102):

[NOOOOOOO](http://nooooooooooooooo.com/) *wheeze* OOOOO!!!

You were one of the first mods I ever saw trying to step outside the flag box. Hanging out with the blurry folks in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). Chipping in on burninates. [Trogdor](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165597/trogdor) was even kinda your idea (OK, it was [all your doing](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41346972#41346972)). And the list! We organized the requests! Even the banter was great.

We will miss you. And your ninja ways.

Answer (score 63):

Jon, as a Python chat RO, you were the first to welcome me to Stack Overflow. Your leadership in the room is a large part of why I stayed with SO years ago, and you've been great as a moderator since then. I could always trust that you'd be around with a level head to mediate any problems, but also be around to hang out, share silly clips of British TV shows, and welcome new users. It's sad to see you leave, but I know you'll promote the spirit of moderation wherever you go next.

Comment: I'm barely ever here logged in these days. I've missed a lot. But I echo @davidism's sentiment wholeheartedly. Room 6 and Jon's welcome in particular got me through some tough days of PhD study.

Answer (score 60):

Aw geez.  Another resignation seemingly out of left field.

I respect your motivations and I respect what you've done for us.
**Thank you.**

Don't be a stranger for those of us still lurking.

Comment: This I do concur!

Answer (score 47):

Jon,

I understand your decision. We've gotten to know each other rather well through the last few months and I'm going to miss hearing your very sensible voice during office hours. While you may be stepping down, I hope we can look forward to seeing you occasionally, and, when I finally make it over to your side of the pond, I hope we can still make it to that pub where they let patrons throw a log on the fire if they wish.

Take care of yourself, most of all.

Comment: Blimey, all these responses must be getting quite soul destroying for you by now. Your tone seems slightly sadder with each one (although it’s fair to say I might be projecting that). Anyway I hope you and shog have something nice to look forward to this weekend, seems like you deserve it more than most

Comment: Clive, well said. There should be a cake & whiskey wishlist service so we can send these two (and whoever else with less visibility is involved in this with the same epic depth and emotional investment - really hard to see from the outside) something nice in solidarity. Somebody make it happen!

Comment: Thanks Tim... it's a date :)

Answer (score 42):

Jon, I'm really sad to see you go.  You've been a great help over the years and I have enjoyed interacting with you in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).  You've taken care of problems and offered guidance and I will always be grateful for that.  Hopefully I still be able to toss you a Scooby Snack in the room sometime ;)

Comment: someone said scooby snacks!? woof woof!

Answer (score 22):

It's been a long time (you probably don't even remember me now, as we didn't know each other very well) but I was active long enough and can say that you were one of the best moderators SO has ever had.  Both on the main site, in the Python chat room.

When you moderated, it was like you were just any other ordinary member.  You were always patient, friendly and approachable, and helped so many people (me included) out of a confusing mess, more than once.  Both through your answers, and through your dedication as a SO mod.

It's sad that you are stepping down, but I think we can all understand.  Being a mod is a great responsibility.  Greater than most of us could handle (being that active and for so long for starters).

I can safely say you have gained a lot of respect as a mod and the way you balanced being a user and a mod, you are an inspiration to the community.

Whatever you do, and wherever you go, good luck and all the best.

I just hope you will still be around to help us. With or without that diamond :)

Answer (score 15):

From a new user's point of view, it's very sad. The community is what made this site. Now moderators are leaving is not a good sign. The fact that moderators are talking about this subject, it's not a good sign. Company management should try to think about the unique value of the community.

Comment: I agree, it isn't a good thing, but Jon Clements has been a mod for  as long as I can remember. I've been a member for over 2 years.  Being a mod here takes a lot.  You have to do daily review queues, they take a lot of time, and mods are expected to do additional ones as well (once you hit 500 rep you will see what I am talking about).  Being a mod you are expected to dedicate at least 2 or 3 hours of your day, every day.  For that reason, if he has changed in his life, and can't dedicate that sort of time.  Then the best he can do is to step down.

Comment: @Simon The gist of your comment is correct. Jon has served as a moderator for approximately forever, and being a moderator is a huge time commitment. But, the expectation is closer to 30 minutes a day (although most of us dedicate *far* more time than that). And the moderator flag queue is very different from the normal review queues available to users. You guys are still the first line of defense, and doing all the reviews there is what ensures that the issues escalated to us are the best use of our time.

Answer (score 8):

Here's some last [scooby snacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scooby_Snacks) for your journey. My heart aches already at missing you.  :'(

Bye little pup.

Comment: Thanks Yvette - they certainly won't go to waste... *friendly hug*

Comment: Don't think it means I'm letting you off the fact that YouTube keeps suggesting me horse related videos though :p

Comment: @JonClements menu > history > find the video > hover > x

Answer (score 4):

Although I don't play his music anymore, let me share a few lines from three of his songs:

1. 'Times were tough, love was not enough...' (When you are alone)
2. 'Badlands you got to live it everyday..' (Badlands)

by Bruce Springsteen (another lost cause for me) ;)

and now for me:

'I am gonna sit back right easy and laugh, When Scooter and the Big Man bust this city in half'... (Tenth avenue {SO} freeze-out) ;)

Take care and we will meet on the flip side!

Comment: Can't say I've been a massive fan of Springsteen - however you've reminded me that actually there's one track I do like [My Hometown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77gKSp8WoRg)

Comment: Yes, when my Son was just 5 we migrated to another country, I played the song for him... didn't think he would remember at 17, but when we returned he reminded me of it...nice song and, sadly, the way of life in North America.

Answer (score 3):

Goodbye, thank you for guiding our community in the correct way.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your services. Hope you will continue helping.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for what you did, and thank you even more for what you've done now.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to see someone so loved and respected by the community step down, but you need to do what's best for you.  Best of luck in future endeavors.

Answer (score -32):

Sad to hear that, but good luck to you. Stack Overflow was filled with a lot of good people who were immediately start to criticize you or moderate your posts very quickly this is what I witness when I started using StackOverFlow. I think they were actually good in correcting ourselves to come to the point earliest as possible.

But, what has changed in Stack Overflow recently is firing by StackOverFlow of moderators, how much it has affected them I don't know.

Comment: As I can see, this user *said good things* about topic. Perhaps his English is not quite good, but... Still don't understand, why it is so heavily downvoted.

Comment: Seems funny, I just saw this after two years