# I'm standing down as a moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-resignation

I'm going to be short and blunt on this.

I'm stepping down as an elected moderator for personal reasons - nothing related to SO.

Heck... the current moderator team is awesome - you're not missing much with my absence.

It's been an absolute pleasure to have served for 7 years.

Cheers, Jon (the cutest yellow puppy with three legs!).

Comment: thanks for those 7 years and hope you'll stay around as a regular user

Comment: May you have find all the bones to chew on! Hoping you will still be a regular presence on the site.

Comment: May your journey to find your missing leg be fruitful. And take care, man. You have always been one of the more popular mods from back in the day.

Comment: No controversy. Good news.

Comment: Oh, I never [knew you're a dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you're_a_dog)!

Comment: It's been one hell of a 49 years!

Comment: Puppy! I hope everything is okay, and we'll still see you around here. Thanks for all the great work you've done for the site, and all the memories of the good ol' Room 6 days. Cheers, mate!

Comment: Thank you for your years of service as Stack Overflow's cutest mod, and best of luck to you with whatever life is throwing your way (good or bad, I'm not sure) that's led to you stepping down.

Comment: All the best to you, I hope to see you again in the python tag!

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the tags, when no one else touched the issue!

Comment: Your help, coaching, support, keeping us in check were crucial in the early days of SOCVR and you continued to support our efforts later on.  I can't express in words how much that was and still is appreciated by me and the RO team. Take care.

Comment: Thanks for the service and help over the years Jon.  Don't forget SOCVR still hands out scooby snacks :)

Comment: I'm upvoting this Jon! or? :) Thanks for everything you done and still hope to see you around in chat.

Comment: Good luck with whatever prompted this decision.

Comment: Jon, thank you for all that you've done in service to this community through the years, and I hope we'll continue to see you around.

Comment: Thanks for all you've done for the community Jon!

Comment: Thanks for all your work, Jon! Hope you can get a fourth leg some time...

Comment: Did you step down twice? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390525/109941

Comment: @JimG. Yes, Jon stepped down from his elected moderator position once before, just as you linked. At some point later (I forget exactly when, and I don't think it matters), he applied for reinstatement, following the standard process. His reinstatement was approved. He's now stepping down again, as he indicates here, for personal reasons. Moderators on Stack Exchange are elected "for life", which means they are allowed to step down when they no longer want to serve *and* are allowed to subsequently apply for reinstatement, if they so choose. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336176

Comment: I just wanna say that I like the edits history of this post.

Comment: I agree the edits are funny. :D

Comment: Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: Shouldn't this have been an overflow blog post?

Comment: @Dragas I don’t think they do blog posts for mods stepping down.

Comment: We'll miss you. Good luck. Come back someday if you can.

Answer (score 145):

Thanks Jon, for everything!

The amount that you've helped me, and the site, is immeasurable. I recall you and poke helping me find my way to the Python room, and spending all those memorable time in those chat rooms. I remember you getting elected, and it was such a emphatic moment for all of us in chat! Also, hey, I remember you editing the "Jon Clements is a bad admin" question on meta.

Even after I became a mod, you helped me to get through those darn user deletion tools, and helping me draw my first blood! Honestly, I'm not sure what I could have done without you.

I really hope that you continue to be active in the site. Thanks again, and good luck in your future endeavours! Sending all the Scooby snacks your way.

Comment: Did you say scooby snacks!? :p

Comment: Yeah... might well have nudged to you to try to elect yourself as a mod as well... from what I recall... you broke all the records :p

Comment: Thanks @poke, those were awesome times indeed. It's been 8 long years! :)

Answer (score 107):

It's been great working with you. Thank you for all the work and time you've contributed over the years.

I wish you all the best in whatever you choose to do in the future. I hope you choose to continue to be around as a regular user. We will definitely miss you on the mod team.

Answer (score 102):

Seven years is a good long time for any mod, but especially converted to dog years!

Seriously - thanks for all the help & service over the years. You've been a real *team player* - looking out for your teammates, stepping up to ensure stuff got talked about, even (especially?) those sorta icky interpersonal conflicts that sometimes we'd all just prefer to ignore.

Hopefully we'll still see you around now and then...

Good luck!

Answer (score 25):

I'm going to miss the most approachable looking moderator in the moderator tab. I mean, just look at the puppy's welcoming smile and large round eyes!

Anyway, hats off to you! *(I'm literally removing my winter bash hat for this.)*

And a [quote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390525/13552470) from yourself...

> Let's keep our best paw forward, yeah?

Answer (score 15):

I remember several interactions with you and have always been happy with your decision making. You were, and still are, a familiar name to the community, so I personally consider this yet another nail in the proverbial coffin - just as it was when you resigned the *first* time.

Thank you for helping to make this place better. I'm pretty sure I owe a non-trivial amount of my Python learning stage paychecks to you. Sad to see such long standing, familiar members leave, but *c'est la vie* I suppose.

Hope all is well with you and your family, happy holidays, and so long!

Answer (score 11):

Thank you so much for your time here, Jon - your time as a moderator has been exemplary.

I'm late to the farewells here, mostly because it's difficult for me to put my feelings into words so I poked around, looking for what I could recognize that would make an impact... numbers came up... 10 years and 10 months of membership and over 3650 days on site... that says a lot of your commitment to the community, regardless of your status of a moderator.

On top of that, there's your work with and stewardship of the [Python sub-community here](https://sopython.com/) that's beyond even what being a moderator entails. Not to mention [your efforts to help others around the world be successful programmers through the Python Software Foundation Jobs board](https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2018/07/), for which you were recognized with the Q1 2018 Community Service Award.

You've shown that you found a place here and worked to help others. That's more than I can hope to ask from the community members here on SO - thank you so much for that!

Thanks for sharing your kindness, insight and care for this site for so long and I sincerely hope that you can enjoy your moderator "retirement". I hope that we'll see you around still, even without the diamond.

Please know that you will be missed and your contributions haven't been overlooked. We will remember you and the work you've done to support so many others here and around the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for such thoughtfulness and kind words Cat _hug_