# 2020 Developer Survey: any topic suggestions?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2020

I’m Anita, a Product Manager here at Stack Overflow.

We are starting to work on the questionnaire for the 2020 Developer Survey. Thanks to you, we had some great questions in the 2019 survey, such as:

- [On average, how many hours per week do you work?](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#work-_-hours-worked-per-week)
- [At what age did you write your first line of code or program?](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-writing-that-first-line-of-code)
- [Does your company regularly employ unit tests in the development of their products?](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#work-_-unit-tests)

(Check out the [results from the 2019 survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019) if you haven’t already.)

We'd love to get your suggestions for compelling topics we should cover this year.

- It's the 10th anniversary of the Developer Survey. Any questions regarding how things have changed in the last decade?
- We are always on the lookout for fun/silly questions, in the tradition of [have you tried turning it off and on again](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-families-and-it-support) and [tabs vs. spaces](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#work-_-tabs-or-spaces).

We are aiming for a much shorter survey this year, so we can't include every idea -- but we always try to include a few of the top-voted suggestions.

As always, thanks for your time and contributions! **Please add your suggestions by Tuesday, Oct. 1.**

Comment: Can we also suggest what NOT to ask?

Comment: Why not ask some why's rather than what's and how's?

Comment: This will be removed from being featured on October 1.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker You might want to include a big banner in the post as well, asking people not to post more answers/comments, or just lock it down.

Comment: @Andreas I've gotten flags about de-featuring it so I'm leaving the comment to let potential flaggers know of its status.

Comment: I just the love the concept of badges, makes me feel like i'm the sheriff in town, i solve bugs and errors and in the name of JUSTICE i use standard coding structure. Let's survey on how many programmers do write standard code, rather than whichever works :p ? ( and their excuses will be because of the pressure from above ). No1 read that article in which it says "Rocket was destroyed before its launched becasue of "A lone omitted hyphen" ".

Comment: Why her reputations is not increasing? :P

Comment: If you're going to ask again about language favourites can you please differentiate between Python2 and Python3? Now that Python2 is basically EOL it would be nice to know how much legacy usage there is. Maybe do the same with PHP, would be nice to know which PHP version people really like.

Comment: @PratikButani Reputation is not awarded for posts on a per-site meta.

Comment: As we are way past **Tuesday, Oct. 1** shouldn't we close the discussion?

Comment: I'd like to see a question regarding to how satisfied the users are regarding to the different services provided by stackoverflow and the direction the company is taking regarding specific points.

Comment: We've received your feedback on the 2020 Developer Survey. Work on crafting the survey has begun. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 484):

I am curious about how often people are *forced* to work on weekends or put in extra hours on workdays.

> How often are you required by your employer to work overtime without proper overtime pay or compensatory time?
>
> - Never
> - Once a month
> - 2-4 days a month
> - 5 days or more in a month

Combining this with geographic or technology data would be interesting.

*Any improvements to the question wording are welcome.*

Comment: @Lundin Just because it is illegal doesn't mean nobody does it. Besides this has been trending in news lately in the context of China. I am just curious about how prevalent it is around the world. And about half of the proposed questions on this page aren't related to programming.

Comment: I'd also be interested in finding that out on top of how many people put in extra time to deliver a project on schedule willingly without being asked along with experience and age ranges.

Comment: Followup question: *Do* you get paid / extra pay for overtime? Would be interesting across countries, across technologies (frontend vs. backend) and across industry sectors (internal IT vs. contracting vs. consulting etc.)

Comment: You don't even need the /forced/ bit. A lot of people do unpaid overtime "willingly", either because they are workaholic or feel likes it is required of them. It would be good to know how much people are doing these kind of overtimes as well.

Comment: In the state of California in the US (where Silicon Valley is), there actually is no concept of overtime for tech employees in many cases. There is a wage order that lumps people into "salaried" positions so long as they meet certain criteria, which almost all tech workers do; as a result most tech employees there are considered "on-call" 24/7 and must work weekends/nights if their bosses require it of them, with no extra pay. Allegedly 85% of Cali workers tech AND non-tech are misclassified as "salaried" when they should be OT-eligible.

Comment: @k0pernikus Yeah, but that's not the point of my question. I am looking for data on certain kind of work environments where people are expected to put in extra hours. That's separate from people being passionate about a project and staying late to finish it. Nevertheless, that would be interesting to know as well. Maybe they could have a couple of follow up questions to seek clarity of other aspects as you and luk2302 mention.

Comment: If submissions can be broken into multiple related questions a of the sort of jurisdictional issues raised in the comments could be avoided by splitting into ex  "How often do you work overtime?"  "Is doing so voluntary or required?"  "Are you given additional compensation for doing so?"

Comment: The "without extra pay" could even be expanded/clarified based on people who are salaried vs hourly.

Comment: @Nisarg the problem is the sketchy grey area between full willingness and forced. My employer wouldn't force me to do anything, but there's an understanding that if a big deadline is close that people should put in some extra time as required/able to do so.

Comment: @mbrig I think it is not that complicated. If you feel that there would be an adverse impact on your career if you don't put in such extra time, then it is forced, else it is not forced. I realize that the distinction is not black and white, but most people would be able to tell if they have to work overtime against their will.

Comment: Good Question! By the way, working overtime "willingly" does no good for the society at large. It is necessary to ban overtime or get paid for every minute you put in.

Comment: Expect a huge number of high-(numeric)value answers from China. Something called the *996 policy* is prevalent here.

Comment: Add a reminder under the question that the survey is anonymous. In bold. :)

Comment: @psubsee2003: Maybe I'm just spoiled, but my interpretation of "proper overtime" is that you get paid extra, either in money or vacation hours, for every hour you are oncall outside of business hours, *or* you receive some equivalent compensation such as a flat bonus (in cases where you work a fixed or predictable number of oncall hours). But it gets trickier if being oncall is an inherent part of your job description and your base salary is correspondingly higher.

Comment: @Kevin when i wrote that comment all it said was "extra pay".  In the current format, my comment is less accurate now

Comment: @psubsee2003: Sure, but even so, I'm not sure if this is always going to be a reasonable question. If everyone was a nominally 9-5 SWE, then it would make sense. But personally, I'm an SRE, and being oncall is an inherent part of my duties. I nevertheless receive extra compensation for it, but I'm not sure it would be "wrong" to move that extra compensation into my base pay.

Comment: I'm particularly interested in whether the "forced" overtime that developers experience tends to be planned in advance, or emergency on-call.

Comment: There should also be an option of "20 or more days in a month"

Comment: @mbrig It's very true that companies rarely really "force" anyone to do anything (e.g., in the US legally you can always quit any job at any time). Maybe the whole gray area of "required" could be avoided if the question were worded something like "Do you do overtime?" followed by "If you stopped, would it have a negative impact on your career?" or "Is it **expected** for employees to do overtime as part of their jobs?"

Comment: @jrh There's a difference too, between overtime that pushes your average working hours above >40hr per week over the year and the more "on-demand"/flexible "overtime". My company is totally cool with me coming in late or leaving early if I feel unproductive/crappy (or just have something to go do), as long as I don't abuse it. They occasionally expect me to put in extra hours, and I'm ok with that too, as long as *they* don't abuse it. Am I really working "overtime"? I dunno... I'd sooner call it "flexible work hours".

Comment: @mbrig I agree. I've worked on projects that actively planned for 70-95 hour weeks for the entire duration of the project (it was expected even in the bidding process and  sometimes customers demanded it, and /or management expected to rake in the overtime premium), then there were projects where it was implied that "you could get more done if you were just willing to stay a little while longer", then there were projects that just slipped slightly (for reasons beyond what somebody could realistically plan for) which caused overtime to try and keep the project on schedule.

Comment: The word "required" also is unclear. While an employer may not specifically state "you just do this...", there could be pressure that you do. I may not be specifically told that I need to work on Saturday night, but the expectation may be there nonetheless. This could be employer driven, or it could be the culture because of employees trying to outshine one another.

Comment: @TheBrewmaster Yeah, jrh addressed an aspect of that in their comment above. It is a complex question, with varying levels of ambiguity. As suggested by others, perhaps this is best handled via multiple questions. I'm sure whoever is reviewing this for the survey, will take the suggestions in the comments into account.

Comment: In Texas, most programming jobs are salary; because, if they were hourly, the cost would be too great.  There is a strong right-to-work law in effect here, which effectively means you have the right to leave your employer, and likewise they have the right to terminate you (with or without a reason).  This means that if you get a new job, the first thing you need to discover is how many "company culturally" acceptable hours of work are expected.  I've seen companies were 60 hours per week was the norm, 50 hours, and rarely, 40 hours.  I've never seen one where less was acceptable.

Comment: I think the question should ask about hours, not about days.  Hours per week or hours per month.

Answer (score 293):

> How often do you exercise or play sports?
>
> - never
> - once a month
> - once a week
> - multiple days a week

I am interested in how true the stereotype is.

Comment: Whenever someone asks this question.

Comment: I improved the options; sorry if it makes anyone's "fun" comments not make sense anymore.

Comment: @Izkata I train 5 days a week. And there was no valid answer I could have choosen before. The current 4 options work for me :D

Comment: This is one of those times I'm so glad the site enables you to view edit history. The original was funny; but now it's also a good question. Win win.

Comment: For useful data we should include time spent. It's not the same exercising 20 minutes or 2 hours. Otherwise, answers might lead to falsey ideas.

Comment: A corollary close to my heart: how close to your workplace/home is your exercise facility, and does your employer provide or subsidize them. I recently joined a firm with an onsite gym and went from the stereotype to going every day.

Comment: @Harry12345   once a week, simple but i do

Comment: @Poutrathor while it's true that exercise can vary, even 20 minutes a day is a great thing over nothing; I think it's adequate to simply ask how active programmers are... we don't need to make *that* deep a dive into the particulars of their physical fitness.

Comment: does a daily 10min bike commute of < 3km count? does biking 50-100km a week count as well? is checker sport? or darts? what about snooker? does walking 2km in your forced breaks count? _nitpicking_

Comment: I am doing a little of cyber-sport every day.. 4-5 hours of borderlands, remnant from ashes, etc. Do I "play sports" or should I install FIFA?

Comment: Do esports count? Asking for a friend.

Comment: My university's line union for my study (1.-5. year students) has a sports interest group, namely for those interested in practicing sports. We're about 500 students, and that group had less than 10 participants last time I checked.

Comment: Maybe we could correlate this later on with life expectancy

Answer (score 230):

How long does it take you to get to work in minutes? `____________` minutes.

---

How long (in minutes) do you want your daily commute to be *at most*? `____________` minutes.

---

What type of transportation do you primarily use to commute to work?

- Public ( bus, train, tram, subway, etc. )
- Private Vehicle ( car, motorcycle, jetpack, etc. )
- Physical Motion ( walk, cycle, skateboard, etc. )
- Not Applicable ( remote, self employed, work on the go, etc. )

Comment: 3 hours :( \*weeps\*

Comment: Wording should make it clearer whether this counts a single journey to/from work or sums up the round trip time.

Comment: @w-m - Generally a commute means how far it is one way. For example, a 20 mile commute means work is 20 miles away. I will clarify it in the post though.

Comment: Add "Not Applicable" -- some people may work from home or not work at all.

Comment: I love telling people I have a 5 second commute, which is how long it takes me to walk from my bedroom to my desk (I work remotely from home).

Comment: I know some cases where people live in their office as well

Comment: I commute 2 hours both ways, so please add more options in the questionaire

Comment: @GaneshKamath-'CodeFrenzy' - The first set of "bins" or "options" was actually not ideal, as pointed out by @ mbx (even though the commute was removed). As a result, the single line question with a freeform box to enter minutes was suggested. In your case, that would just be an entry of 120 in the minutes box. What other options did you have in mind?

Comment: If this question is asked, please clarify "round trip" hours.  There's a lot of us who are used to the concept of "hours to arrive at the office" as the "commute time".

Comment: If I stop at a StarBucks every single morning, does that count towards my commute?

Comment: lol @Rainbolt, I often do the same thing. I don't think that counts though ;)

Comment: @EdwinBuck - In its current state, it simply asks "How long does it take you to get to work in minutes?" Is that not clear enough? I would think that is the interpretation you share of commute as well when you define it as "hours to arrive at the office" as the "commute time".

Comment: @TravisJ Commutes are not one way.  Many places have imbalanced times to arrive at work an to leave from work.  For example, my "return home" drive time is easily 15 minutes more than my "arrive at work" drive time.  So, I'd like it if the question was modified to "how much time do you spend (in minutes) commuting to and from work"

Comment: I think this should go up to at least 2 hours. (Personally, my commute is nearly 2 hours)

Comment: @ThomasHarris I would have it go up to 4.  My commute is (round trip) 2.5 hours, should I do the normal leave / arrive times.

Comment: What type of transportation do you primarily use to commute to work?
It depends on season. During the cold season it a bus during th warm season it a bicycle. What should I select?
On my previous job it was the guy who commute with train and bicycle. What should he select? Is it possible add item "it depends" or "multiple"?

Answer (score 224):

Display habits:

- How many computer monitors are you using for your job?  1 / 2 / 3 / 4 or more
- Is one or more of them vertically oriented? (inspired by very long function frustration)
- What are the sizes of the monitors you are using? (in inches)
- How many different program windows are visible on your screen at the same time? (credit for @Bergi)

Comment: Do you use a beamer / IMAX ....

Comment: What about projectors?

Comment: Maybe: how many different program windows are visible on your screen at the same time?

Comment: If you need a special monitor in order to read your source, then you have much bigger problems than monitors to worry about...

Comment: I'm using 5 monitors. (Just pointing out that "4" may not be an adequate maximum response option for this question.) https://blog.jonschneider.com/2018/04/my-five-monitor-macbook-pro-setup.html

Comment: @JonSchneider I think we could stop at 4 at write it as "4 and more".

Comment: @Lundin I mean it can actually be really helpful to have a vertical monitor for reading source code even if the code is well-written.

Comment: @Clonkex Back in the command-line days we had at most 25 lines on screen and it worked just fine then. With normal 1920x1200 resolution and a normal IDE, you get somewhere between 60 to 80 lines. If that's not enough, then one either has some severed malformed source code or one is a poser who must show off by having a special monitor. In either case, the monitor isn't the problem.

Comment: Is that question for pro or personnal computer ?

Comment: @Cid - I meant that to be for professional programmers

Comment: @Clonkex Any function that doesn't fit on my 4K monitor is getting refactored.

Comment: @Lundin things that are "enough" can still be improved upon. Seeing all of a larger class definition can be nice. I tend to read library documentation on a vertically oriented monitor. Its just nicer sometimes.

Comment: @Lundin Since when does a "back in my day" story mean we can't improve?? Wtf? Just because you were able to program on a tiny screen "just fine" doesn't mean it's not helpful to be able to see more code. I don't get your reasoning. Sometimes it's just really nice to be able to see more than one function at once, especially if they're related. Or, you know, not have to scroll as much.

Comment: @TKK Good for you? Not sure why you're telling me that.

Comment: @Clonkex Eh well there's this thingie called multiple windows :) (Even them 25 line DOS editors like Turbo C had multiple windows.) If one single source file takes up the whole high resolution screen, both in terms of length and width, then there can be no doubt something is very wrong with the code.

Comment: Isit possible to make the monitors a number entry field? Or do all responses have to be from a fixed set?

Comment: @Clonkex Your comments to others indicate that you're missing something key. Monitor size was never the reason to keep classes and functions short. It's not helpful to be able to see more code because the code shouldn't be that long to begin with.

Comment: Thanks. I need a justifiable, articulable reason to get a new monitor.

Comment: 1 vertical, 1 horizontal for me.  Best of both worlds.

Comment: @Lundin Wtf? I strongly disagree that if a source file doesn't fit in a single screen it's too long. That's total nonsense.

Comment: @TKK ???? When did I even vaguely imply that monitor size is why we keep functions short?? It's very helpful to see more code because there's always more code to see. I don't understand what kind of code you're looking at where you can see the entire file in one horizontal screen.

Comment: "What is the size of the monitors you using? (in inches)" -- Maybe include aspect ratios, too? A 4:3 monitor (are those still used somewhere?) shouldn't be considered the same as an ultra-wide monitor.

Comment: @JonSchneider You need at least three more to see the full Enterprise.

Comment: A lot of these answers are great but this would be a fascinating one. I am provided with at least 3 monitors but find myself using just one the majority of the time. This could be because I learned to program on a laptop and have become accustom to using one display and switching between apps and windows via the keyboard. I’ve also seen my coworkers use vertical displays which is interesting to me. Would love to see what typical industry habits are.

Comment: "What are the sizes (in inches)" is nice, but I'm more interested in resolution. "What resolution(s) do you use (check all that apply)".  And/or "How many total pixels do you have (add up across all monitors) => <2MP, 2-8 MP, 8-12 MP, 12-15, 15-18, 18+" Something like that

Comment: @David - They have pixel data already.

Answer (score 189):

> If you were looking for a job, how much time (in days) of remote work would you
>   want to be allowed to do?
>
> - No remote work - I like being in an office
> - 1-2 days a week
> - 3-4 days a week
> - Full time remote
> - Flexible remote time - as requested or required by life circumstances

Inspired by a colleague of mine that I want to work with me but he only wants to work remote.

Comment: I think "you want to be allowed to do" should be rephrased. Even if I would work almost always in the office, it would still be nice to have the *option* of remote work, so I'm not sure what I would choose here. Or is the question about if I care how much colleagues are allowed to work remotely?

Comment: I think the question needs context to how far you'd need to commute otherwise. I'm fine with no remote work when I can bike to the office in 15 minutes, but would think otherwise if I'd need to take the bus for an hour.

Comment: Agreeing with @kapex here. I like that my job _allows_ me to work remotely _whenever I need to_ (e.g. medical appointment next to my place, why on earth should I commute 4 times that day?), however I'd probably hate it if they _forced_ me to work remotely any given number of days a week. **Maybe rephrase to _"What degree of freedom to work from home would you want to be given?"_** Answers may include the above options and also things like _"X fixed days every week"_, _"X days a month, freely distributed"_, etc.

Comment: Nice one! I hate working from home!

Answer (score 152):

> Which beverage do you turn into code?
>
> 1. Coffee
> 2. Tea
> 3. Soft drink
> 4. Alcohol
> 5. Energy drink
> 6. Water
> 7. Milk
> 8. Chocolate milk
> 9. Juice

Sub-question is:

> How many servings of your beverage do you drink on average in a day?
>
> 1. I don't have any
> 2. 1
> 3. 2 - 3
> 4. 4 or more

Comment: The question could be "Which beverage you turn into code? Coffee, Tea, Soda, Alcohol, Energy drink, Water" Then "How many drinkware do you drink on average in a day?".

Comment: That ↑ being said, now that the question includes several beverages, it might be better to invert the question and subquestion, i.e. _"Q: How many cups of your beverage do you have on a working day? None, 1, 2-3, 4+"_; and only if a positive answer is given, then _"SQ: Which beverage is it?"_ to avoid having to include a "no beverage" option in _both_ questions.

Comment: The use of the word "soda" is very region specific, might want to add pop/fizzy drinks/etc

Comment: @walen You could add the option "I don't drink while coding" in the first question and hide the second one if that's the case.

Comment: If I tried to turn water into code all I would get is a fried computer.

Comment: Would it be possible for this to be a multiple choice question? I turn many of those into code.

Comment: The question "How many servings of your beverage do you drink on average in a day?" feels weird when it's water: while it's fairly easy to count how many cups of coffee one drinks each day on average, I doubt anyone who drinks water could say "I drink xx glasses of water each day"

Comment: @Dada Liters would be a better metric for water.

Comment: @towe No it wouldn't: while it's arguably interesting to see how many cups of coffee one drinks in a day, nobody cares about how many liters one drinks each day.

Comment: @Dada Except the fact that doctors regularly make multi-liter recommendations for daily water consumption... it may surprise you that many programmers do care about (that aspect of) their health.

Comment: "0 / 1 / 2–3 / 4+"? Those are rookie numbers!

Comment: why do people hammer on liquids? I turn food into code! Water and tea I drink to basically not die of dehydration.

Comment: Because after I finish eating I am sleepy ofc ... that's why full time on coffein makes me go mad mode and can type into this keyboard for full 12 hours strait without making a break, then i get in a mode where I don't even look what I am typing and I just keep typing and keep drinking coffee and so I am typing even more that way ...

Comment: One day hot chocolate will be mainstream. @Gimby Drinking is easier than eating, and there's no need for utensils to keep things tidy, preventing your KB/M from being sticky and crumby.

Comment: this is really dumb.

Comment: It was awesome, before tea lovers ...

Comment: We need additional questions for people answering 4 and 4

Comment: Please include milk tea as a separate option.

Comment: Seems sort of wrong to dehumanize developers as beverage code conversion machines.

Comment: I am pretty sure most of developers around here know who they are, it's just about fun and games ... and also figuring out how many caffeine insomnia junkies we have around ... as I know at least 2

Answer (score 142):

Even today many services store sensitive information in plain text which gets leaked time to time. My suggestion would be regarding this,

> Does your company store sensitive information (password, card numbers,
>   etc...) of customers in plain text?
>
> - Yes, I have tried to stop this practice.
> - Yes, I believe we have to store info as plaintext due to various requirements.
> - Yes, I haven't spoken to my management about it.
> - No, sensitive information is not stored in plain text.
> - No, we do not store sensitive information at all.
> - I don't know.
> - Prefer not to answer.
> - Not Applicable.

Improvements to the question are welcome.

Comment: Well, storing it MD5-encrypted isn't really much better...

Comment: There is also another group of companies: Those that save encrypted password (along with decryption key), and decrypt it at the time of login to compare with input value. :P

Comment: Sometimes storing passwords isn't the problem but some loopholes exist. It could be generalized by "Are you satisfied by the level of security your sofware/service offers".

Comment: This question seems vague/judgemental. I can have a legitimate usecase for needing card numbers as plaintext. I can run pseudosecurity by encrypting it and storing the encryption key (TDE and such), but if that makes it better is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @ErikA When would you need to store card numbers as plaintext?

Comment: @DavidG When running a credit card company, for example. I personally store a lot of other sensitive PII, btw, but not credit card numbers.

Comment: @ErikA But you can store PII encrypted or at least psuedoanonymised (GDPR requires it in some cases for example, there's no need to store these values in plaintext.

Comment: @DavidG If you run a credit card company, you can't store the PII pseudonymized, because you have a legitimate goal for having that PII available to you. As said, you can run TDE (encrypting the data and storing an encryption key in a hard-to-reach place that's still available to the system), but that's not much better than not encrypting it at all, assuming you own your servers and properly employ physical security and access control.

Comment: @ErikA I don't think you appreciate what psuedonmyisation is here, the original value are still able to be retrieved, but the data is not stored in plaintext. It is encrypted in some way, perhaps using some form of steganography.

Comment: @DavidG But the data needs to be linkable in real time. There's no use case for pseudonymization. If you visit the credit card companies web site, you expect to be able to see both your name and your credit card number. You can run "pseudonymization" in the sense of obfuscating your database, but that's a solution asking for a problem while creating a whole lot of other problems in the mean time. Anyway, working with such data often involves external audits, so the programmer is not the party to raise such concerns.

Comment: @ErikA Not sure what you mean by "linkable", but the data is certainly visible in realtime, it just needs to go through a suitable algorithm. As for programmers no raising such concerns, I'd also vehemently disagree with that too. I would be appalled if one of my devs felt they couldn't raise a concern. Sure that concern may not be accurate, but as long as there is a good reason for it. Anyway, we started this by you saying CC numbers could be stored in plaintext, and that is fundamentally what I disagreed with :)

Comment: @Nisarg Isn't that how Windows credentials work?

Comment: What if they store the password as encrypted but they have the private key in plaintext in the same directory?

Comment: This could be broadened to insecure practices in general. Storing passwords (an example of data that shouldn't be accessible to anyone but the user) in plain text is just one example. Others might be SQL injections, weak hashes, and so forth.

Comment: Wouldn't answering this question lead to security concerns?

Comment: Add the option 'Yes, and we are in the process of fixing this'

Comment: I agree that this is important to discuss, but the discussion is always going to be complicated and nuanced. This question and its associated options is too simplistic. For example, my SSN is stored in plain text on my social security card which is locked in a safe in my house. Pretty sure it's safe from internet hackers. I'm much more worried about a bank that is still using DES to encrypt my bank account info.

Comment: Let the "Lawyers' Anxiety Games" begin

Comment: Can we add the option for "yes, and I don't care/doesn't bother me"

Answer (score 132):

How much time do you spend a week programming on non-work related projects (e.g. hobby projects, open source...)?

- 0 - I don't program in my spare time
- < 1 hour
- 1 - 3 hours
- 4 - 6 hours
- 6 - 9 hours
- 9+ hours

I'm wondering if there is a correlation between how long you've been in the industry and how much programming you do outside of work.

Comment: The more I'm in the industry, the less programming I do at home. But that's because when I was a junior I went into it 100% and was working on 4-5 projects at home just to keep filling a huge knowledge gap. Nowadays I learn things quickly and I do projects more for fun... and I suck at coming up with fun projects I can stick with till completion.

Comment: @Gimby '*I suck at coming up with fun projects I can stick with till completion.*' - I struggle with the last half of your sentence.

Comment: Happens more in waves for me. There will be a month or couple months where I don't do to much outside of work other than read about tech and trends, Followed by being consumed every waking moment with coding my personal project or proof of concepts.

Comment: @script47 Hmm, let me rephrase. I don't need to do projects to learn anymore so I try to do projects for fun. But I have trouble coming up with projects that are actually fun, which means I'm stuck :)

Comment: I'm not sure there would be a conclusive correlation there. Some people just love programming and do some in their spare time regardless of how long they've been in the industry - they could be new university graduates or people with 15-20 years of experience. Similarly, others just don't enjoy doing things at home. Maybe because looking at code at work is enough for them, maybe because they just went with programming for the money and don't really like it overall. Or others. I've met both of types - who like or don't like programming in their spare time and experience didn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 115):

> You are put in a room with 100 random developers who have similar roles to you. Given the traits you value in a strong developer, how many do you think are **better developers** than you?
>
> - 0-10
> - 11-20
> - 21-30
> - ...

Similar to [the 1981 study](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001691881900056?via%3Dihub) that found that 93% of American drivers say they believe their driving skill is "better than average."

I've tried to model the question after the way that groups were tested in the study. They were given the following:

> We would like to know about what you think about how safely you drive an
>   automobile. All drivers are not equally safe drivers. We want you to compare your own skill to the skills of the other people in this experiment. By definition, there is a least safe and a most safe driver in this room. We want you to indicate your own estimated position in this experimental group (and not, e.g., Eugene, Oregon or in the U.SJ (or (and not e.g., people in Stockholm or in Sweden)). Of course, this is a difficult question because you do not know all the people gathered here today, much less how safely they drive. But please make the most
>   accurate estimate you can.

It would be interesting to see how this works with the unique "coding culture" and how it differs from country to country.

I'd be happy to hear suggestions to reword this to be closer to the study and elicit a more natural response. My fear is that it may be worded a bit awkwardly at the moment.

Comment: Above [which average?](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/10/20/nearly-everyone-is-above-average/). The question should be worded more like the study, which asked where people would rank themselves relative to others. "The responses were given on a percentile scale by marking one of 10 successive 10 percent intervals." And I think it should be asked where people are relative to other programmers.

Comment: Great points, @Laurel. I looked a little closer at the study and tried to rework the question to be more in the spirit of what they'd done. Thank you for the criticisms! Let me know if you think it can be edited further.

Comment: There was some similar question last year and unsurprisingly, most people were "better than the average".

Comment: Which *may* be absolutely correct for the SO users, it *may* very well be that the average SO user is far better than the average developer. Comparing the two groups and only asking one group (the SO users) will not yield any useful result imho.

Comment: I see no reason coders are likely to answer any differently from car drivers, carpenters or clowns: on average, the population will think they're better than average, as that's simply how human bias works absent an objective ranking (e.g. sports). Even if they did answer "more accurately" than 93%, we could not even conclude coders are better at gauging their own abilities: they might just be more humble or self-deprecating, knowing that coding is hard. This question isn't completely pointless, but it almost warrants a study of its own if you want to get anything useful out of it.

Comment: Current wording is unclear.  Is the best rank 1 or 100?  Also seems weird to have a ranking 0-indexed.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Don't you dare criticize 0-indexing on a programming survey! :D But it is true that the ranking should either be `0-9, 10-19, ...` or `1-10, 11-20, ...`; it doesn't make sense to mix both.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I was imagining "rank" would mean "the number of developers you believe you're better than," which would make 0 a valid answer. I can see how that'd be confusing given my wording though. I've fixed it!

Comment: @luk2302 on the contrary, usually there's a survey question asking about how involved the user is in the SO community. Looking at a correlation between those answers and answers to this could prove interesting.

Comment: Are those 100 programmers from the same country as me? Because "same job title" may imply different roles, backgrounds and/or set of skills in different countries.

Comment: @walen if I swapped "*with the same job title as you*" for "*in a similar role to you*" or "*with the same job description as you,*" would that make it less ambiguous? I think I do want to look at how developers view themselves on an international level to make trends in certain countries more obvious (do a lot of X devs think they're worse than the rest of the world?). But I'm not sure how I'd word that.

Comment: @scohe001 That looks like a good change. It might not be the perfect wording, but it's something.

Comment: "by definition" by which definition? As posed the question is unanswerable.

Comment: @TylerH by the definitions of "best" and "worst." Can you elaborate on how you think I can improve this? Simply saying this is unanswerable without any reasoning isn't very helpful for me :)

Comment: @scohe001 What makes you the "best" programmer? Most years of experience? Most lines of code written overall? per day? Most languages worked with? Most languages *currently* working with? Highest pay? Ability to write fewest lines of code to accomplish a task? Ability to write readable code/comments? Most pupils and beginner programmers taught/mentored on the job? There are endless metrics here.

Comment: Ahh I had that exact thought when I wrote this @TylerH. My cop out is that the study I'm modeling this after did the same thing. What makes you the "safest" driver? How often you stay within the speed limit? How soon you put your blinker on? How "alert" you are of your surroundings? (how would you even measure that?) I think the subjective nature of the question of "best" programmer is exactly the point of this. I'm more interested in seeing how developers subjectively identify themselves (as opposed to how good they objectively actually are).

Comment: @scohe001 That makes it a bit clearer; I'd recommend adjusting the question to say "best programmer *overall*". Similar to foot races, where they have 'overall' winners as well as winners divided by subgroups like age and sex.

Comment: I would put it differently. _"You are one of 100 random developers in a room. How many of them do you expect to be **better developers** than you?"_. If you answer that via number input you can substract the answer from 100 to get the participants perceived skill level. You can subsitute "better" for "more capable" but it doesn't answer what that means anyway.

Comment: I think this is a great idea, I've always felt that the Dunning-Kruger effect is quite common in the industry, would be interesting to see if that holds up. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect

Comment: Ooh I like it @SørenD.Ptæus! I added a little to it to try to emphasize that what I'm looking for here is a subjective opinion. Thanks for the critique!

Comment: What do you mean by a similar role? In my case should I be comparing myself to other interns or other full stack developers?

Comment: It's a bad question... just like the average driver survey is a bad question. It's quite possible that 93% of drivers are better than average _for their use case_

Comment: I know these kind of questions are fun and all but I'd probably skip this one (without a 'I don't know'-ish kind of answer. the only time ranking maybe makes sense is if you had two developers working on the exact same project at the exact same time, on the same team, with the same requirements and equal backgrounds (good luck figuring out whether backgrounds are equivalent); can most developers prove an algorithm's correctness faster than Knuth? Probably not. Can some of them develop code for some obscure, proprietary system better than him? Maybe.... Who wins?

Comment: Define better and at what task. There are lots better than me when it comes to certain specialized tasks, there are lots better when it comes to coding practices, but overall I'm probably above average, while in the domain I am currently in I am still utterly new and would probably ~30th (lower) percentile. 

If you wanted to compare me to front-end, I'd probably be better than most in e.g. CSS grid, working with WP, etc. as I did it to pay my way through college and the average person doing this type of work sucks at it.

Answer (score 101):

> What is your opinion on open plan workspaces?
>
> - I like open workspaces
> - I prefer to work alone
> - A bit of both

Comment: "A bit of both" doesn't really fit imo. It sounds like "sometimes this, sometimes that", whereas the reality is probably more often "sharing an office with a handful of people".

Comment: What is the best number of coworker in a room to achieve work? "1 ; [2,4] ; pizza team [5,7] ; two-pizza team [8,15] ; open space[16, ∞])"

Comment: What shall I answer if I prefer to work in teams of 5-8 devs?

Comment: I don't think liking open workspaces and preferring to work alone are opposite choices.

Comment: @MaxLanghof My answer is "a bit of both"; it depends on the day and what exactly I'm doing.

Comment: @luk2302 5-8 devs is a pizza team. (around half-dozen)

Comment: @aloisdg yeah, your suggestions for the answers is better, just the original alternatives do not fit.

Comment: there is no 5-8 range. it's 6-8.

Comment: Having an office is not the same thing as working alone for what it's worth. You can just have "office per small team" and put 2-3 people in each office.

Comment: Well, my ecosystem is somewhat different, even strange.
I work at office (aka lab) from midnight until roughly 10 am, so most of the time I work in empty office, but during the last couple of hours I work with half-dozen collegues, including my boss.

I'm unable to work remotely, as I'm developing firmware for prototypes, that are located in the office.

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the type of role one's working in? I'd assume some kind of programming/developer jobs require a more active interaction with co-workers than others. In that sense, an answer to this question is context based. An absolute, always valid answer cannot be given if this is the case.

Comment: To me this is more about the *ability* to get privacy/quiet when needed. e.g. Open concept is fine if everyone has headphones... and I can go somewhere to take a private/quiet phone call. I'd prefer a private office, but most offices don't have enough space for everyone to have this.

Comment: Best is half the office is open plan, other half closed, if working as pair/team go to open office plan, if doing something solo and not wanting to be distracted, go to closed/quiet area. 

Currently have that for our small business, 12 people though, not sure how one would do it if an office had 30+, way too much floor space required then.

Answer (score 89):

> What do you listen to while you work?
>
> - Nothing
> - Music (specify genre)
> - White noise
> - My colleagues arguing
> - etc.

Comment: Most of them - sometimes even at the same time.

Comment: What is the difference between arguing colleagues and white noise?

Comment: Music drowns out the colleagues and the white noise. Don't get me started on the nothing.

Comment: @Yunnosch A water fountain makes white noise and while it may be loud, it covers the surrounding noise (i.e. from traffic). That's why city planners love them. Arguing colleagues on the other hand are even worse than a married couple during divorce fighting for custody and material possessions.

Comment: @mbx Ah I see. You mean that your colleagues partially make sense while arguing. (Lucky you, mine don't.) Of course that is more distracting...

Comment: @Yunnosh they regularly do, often they have different angles of on the topic and need to sync in order to understand the problem as a whole. It's most distracting, if you yourself know part of problem and have yet another perspective and engaging in that conversation could actually help understand the problem even better and thus improve a solution. Then again, you have other work to do, which needs focus too.

Comment: *etc.* Definitely *etc.*

Comment: I like the genre, but please as pre-defined multiple choice, not as custom input like last year that was a bit messy..

Comment: Podcasts should be an option...... unless I'm alone

Comment: UK's Radio 4 - so mainly politicians arguing at the moment :-)

Comment: genre option: old video game music from my childhood, turned into soothing melancholy softness

Answer (score 87):

For full-timers: how many hours do you spend on actual work (e.g. programming) from all working hours (including daily meetings, coffee breaks, etc.)?

Comment: Does reading count as actual work?

Comment: I consider developing my skills (eg. reading) as part of actual work, as long as I balance it and don't let it interfere with my assigned tasks. But I almost never consider meetings as work unless I'm blissfully ignoring the speaker and working while at the meeting ;)

Comment: This is going to be subjective, since lots of people working as programmers also are explicitly employed to do other things (project management, customer interaction, server/DB/version control maintenance etc etc).

Comment: @Bergi I'd say it depends on what you're reading: if it's required for your work, then yes - it's a part of work, but you find interesting blog post about programming and you want to read it just because you like it, then no.

Comment: @Lundin so it can be counted as actual work hours, since they were explicitly asked to do it on work.

Comment: Does answering on Stack Overflow count as actual work?

Comment: @aloisdg I think no, you're doing it for yourself, since the work can be done without answering here. But submitting a question can be count as work, because it helps to solve concrete work issues.

Comment: @Kirill it is mostly a joke comment. Answering question can be seen as an exercise and so a way to improve your skill. The challenge is more often to understand OP need than to find the solution. Soft skills are hard.

Comment: Rephrase the question to not devalue other work, as in: "how many hours do you spend on actually programming from all working hours?"

Comment: @DavyM: If your meetings don't count as work, your company has a bad meeting culture. There are techniques for turning meetings into productive uses of time. I highly suggest you look into those and try to change your company culture.

Comment: I'd define "actual work" as anything that your boss would be OK with paying you to do during work hours; alternatively, anything your boss would not be concerned about even if s/he found you doing it during work hours.

Comment: Maybe we could rephrase this question as this : "_Which activities do you consider "working", and which ones your employer consider work?_" : Rows are "Coding, Reading, attending to meeting, speaking in a meeting, lunch, exchanging with colleagues about work around coffee, helping move offices, answering phone calls on leave, etc...", columns are "I consider it as work" and "my employer consider this as work", and add astimated time spent on each one

Comment: An alternative could be "how much time do you spend on your own tasks"?

Comment: Not sure if this is a good question, as it basically asks people who benefit from lying about a value that would only be useful if all answers are honest.

Answer (score 76):

If you lost access to online help/documentation for one workday, could you still develop without using Google, online documentation, or SO?

- Yes, I can productively code and only refer to offline documentation.
- Yes, but I'd hate it
- Yes, but the code would be unacceptably poor quality
- Yes, but it would take an unacceptable amount of time
- No, I'd be stuck

There are lots of different ways to ask this question, so I'm not sure if this is the best way. Another way would be to ask what percentage of your project's tasks could be completed.

Comment: Losing internet basically means I have to revert back to strategies from the time before the internet: scan through existing code to find out / remember how to do things. It's very rare that I need to do something not done in at least one other project already. The benefit of doing nothing cutting edge, I guess. Not sure which bullet that would fall under...

Comment: I have never tried it so I wouldn't know.

Comment: I only refer to SO and other docs about 1/month professionally (it's a LOT more when working with newly-released or preview-version tech). I don't fit into either the first or second bullets :(

Comment: How long have I been working with that code stack? If it's something I'm familiar with and it's only a logic problem, then no internet/docs would probably be fine, if it's a stack specific issue (e.g. I'm not completely familiar with Golang's documentation for a lot of things), then I'd be stuck.

Comment: I'm old enough that I at least have the habits of printed documentation, but my employer doesn't actually provide hard-bound documents more recent than about 10 years, so internet outages really cut into productivity.

Answer (score 75):

How much of your time is spent fighting fires vs working on new features?

- No Firefighting, All Features
- Some firefighting, mostly features
- Even split
- Mostly firefighting, some features
- What is this mystical thing you’re calling new features?

Comment: I doubt many programmers fight fires in their spare time.

Comment: @JL2210 - Sometimes the facilities guy tries to weld on the wrong part and #firefighter happens.

Comment: In case nobody understood my comment: What is the real meaning of this?

Comment: @JL2210 Firefighting = Someone calls the attention of a developer to do non-feature related work... e.g. “(Customer is down / Production is down/ Name emergency here ) ... we need development to fix it”

Comment: All of a sudden, I'm afraid of what I'll get into after I graduate from college...

Comment: Bug fixing is also firefighting, no?

Comment: I would say there's plenty of work between firefighting (being tasked with unplanned work) and implementing **new** features. Testing, profiling, tuning, optimizing and **refactoring** existing code falls into neither category for me.

Comment: What if firefighting is actually your job? It sounds pretty negative turned that way, doesn't it?

Comment: @JL2210 Were you under the impression you would only be sitting at a job writing new code all the time? :-P

Comment: @TylerH Umm... yeah? I'm not going into customer support.

Comment: @JL2210 Then you have a lot to learn about the daily life of a programmer! It involves meetings, dealing with managers, dealing with clients, training people, writing documentation, changing scopes, and so much more fun.

Comment: Does actual fighting of live fire count? I work with electronics... On a more serious note (and given that a lot of participants aren't native English), maybe use a less ambiguous term? Maintenance?

Comment: @JL2210 Each time you develop a product, it afterwards turns out that you alone are the single-most suitable person in the world to maintain that product. Even if it isn't what you are supposed to be doing. The longer you stay with one employer, the more such past projects you'll end up with. If you are lucky, they let the rookie employees maintain old stuff and let the veterans develop new stuff (healthy practice). But even in such an utopia, the rookie programmers will know who made the thing in the first place and come to stalk you.

Comment: @Lundin Can you give a few examples? I want to be prepared.

Answer (score 72):

> Can you exit Vim?
>
> - Yes
> - No
> - What's Vim?
> - I buy a new computer each time.

(Some context: https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/23/stack-overflow-helping-one-million-developers-exit-vim/)

Comment: You forgot: Yes, but I am still writing the program I started 2 years ago.

Comment: Nope, didn't forget that. I didn't include it.

Comment: sorry, I cant give you  a bounty

Comment: Missing option? "Yes, by closing the terminal window, or rebooting the computer."

Comment: For the users that respond "No", make a pop-up that says "Press escape, then colon, then type 'wq'".

Comment: @JL2210 a similar suggestion (just opposite - if yes, pop open a terminal and prove it) was deleted. I doubt it's implementable

Comment: Or refer them to the question.

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/GHrvj0UodzBfi/giphy.gif

Answer (score 57):

I'm interested in how many companies provide desks with electronically adjustable height (so you can switch between sitting and standing), and how much this differs between large cooperations and startups, also by country.

> Do you want to use a standing desk at work?
>
> - Yes
> - No
>
> Does your employer provide standing desks?
>
> - Yes, all desks are standing desks
> - Yes, employees can request those
> - No

Improvements / edits to the question are welcome.

Comment: I dont really like standing desk. Also, I am a kneeling chair user. My wish as a dev for my employer is to let me use any product that can improve my work quality. I would love if this question would adapt to any kind of product.

Comment: You also should consider cases where the standing desk is something that is just put on top of a normal desk and not a true standing desk as they have a smaller desk space

Comment: Maybe this could be generalized to any ergonomic workplace equipment, e.g. ergonomic chairs?

Comment: After having one of these for some time and the novelty wore off, the question is rather "How often do you remember that you actually have a standing desk?"

Comment: My desk is adjustable but it uses a spring mechanism rather than an electric one - it is equally (if not more) easy to use than electronic mechanisms I have used in the past.

Comment: Where I work all developers have desks that can be raised into standing desks, all other employees have normal desks, but can request a standing one.

Comment: Does your employer provide a "voice-activated" standing/sitting desk like StackExchange does for Jay?

Comment: How would sole-proprietorships/freelancers answer the second question?

Comment: Note that some desks are permanent standing desks, and others can be adjusted but it requires tools and a lot of time. Not all standing desks are motorized or easily adjustable.

Comment: At my office we have some standing desks available and not everyone can request them. Perhaps that could be an answer as well.. "Yes, some that are shared between employees"

Answer (score 55):

If your organization was to reduce your number of working days/hours by 1/5 (5 days to 4 days, 40 hours to 32 hours), how much would the productivity be affected?

1. Productivity would increase.
2. Would stay the same
3. Would decrease less than 1/5th
4. Would decrease 1/5th
5. Would decrease more than 1/5th

Comment: Of the entire company or of oneself? I think most of us have very little to judge the former by (other than studies that "said so") so I'm not sure what you think the answers will tell you...

Comment: I think if we ask of oneself, that would reduce the variables a bit at least.

Comment: I think you meant 40 hours to 32 hours. 1/5 of 40 is 8.

Comment: @kukis yup, everyday, I lower the expectation bar for myself.

Comment: I like the question, but how can answers be anything except a guess?

Comment: How about also "Would decrease, but by less than 1/5."

Comment: @DavidG yeah, I do agree that it's more of just taking a guess.

Comment: Good question, but I really think that productivity, should be replaced with something like: "How would that affect the total amount of work done in a week." because productivity may understood as "Amount of work done per worked hour".

Comment: This is a great question, but it might not be a good fit for the developer survey. I would prefer survey questions to be about personal facts and maybe personal preferences. This question on the other hand seems to ask for an opinion or estimate.

Comment: Rather than decreasing a day its good to have only 6 or 7 working hr a day.

Comment: Depends on the tasks for the week, if it's something "new" then probably same or slight increase, if it's just monkey coding like, then probably decrease. Forcing 8 hours though would decrease my productivity, even though I often do 10 hours when feeling productive, I'd burn out fast if forced to stay when not feeling it; plus if I get the work done, hours should not matter. A developer not burning out is heavily dependent on PM, and it's usually the biggest complaints I hear from others, luckily I haven't had a bad PM yet.

Answer (score 51):

On average, how many hours a day do you spend in front of a computer, *outside of work*?

1. Less than an hour
2. One to three hours
3. Three to five hours
4. More than five hours

Comment: Yes lets keep it at "more than five hours" so I don't have to be confronted with how sad my life is.

Comment: And dont use "in front of a screen". At that point we can just count the the time spend sleeping.

Comment: Here again I have to say: let them input an (unsigned) integer and cluster them in buckets afterwards.

Comment: This question has a tinge of sarcasm. You might as well go ahead and ask: "Do you have a life outside of work?"

Comment: Can I consider smartphone or tablet PC as a computer? If I can the answer will 3 otherwise 1

Comment: @aloisdg Assuming we don't fall asleep in front of a screen :)

Comment: I think answers 2 and 3 need rewording - what if my answer is exactly three hours?

Answer (score 49):

**Q:** How important do you consider licensing agreements to be?

1. Very: they are the sole protection we have against IP theft;
2. Somewhat: we should have them, but I generally don't care about enforcement;
3. Screw it! Unilateral, third-party relicensing of my content without warning is just fine.

Comment: Context for those unaware: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333094/332043, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333678/332043, and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333615/332043

Answer (score 47):

How about a question on the most common commuting method? Especially if, in the results, the data could be combined with geographic and or age data, this could show some interesting results.

```
What is your common commuting method?
 - Public transport
 - Cycling
 - Running
 - Walking
 - Driving
 - I work from home
```

I am sure there is already a question in the survey about commute time.

Comment: Has to be a multi-select question. A lot of people will use, e.g., subway and tram in metropolitan areas.

Comment: Rather just say "public transit" to cover bus, tram, or train (subway is just a train that travels underground--no need to specify that one) in one option. Also I'm not sure how many responses we will get for "running"... might be best to just fold that in as "walking/running", not because no one runs to work, but because *everyone* has probably found themselves running when late :-P.

Comment: I am completely fascinated by how this currently has five upvotes and five downvotes. I wonder which of these are the most divisive answers. +1 because commute method and time are important.

Comment: This would have to be correlated to distance to be really interesting.

Comment: @TKK Agree, but there are issues with that. Some places, it's illegal travelling by foot/cycling through, for instance underwater tunnels. Others may bring their cycle on the bus, thereby only cycling some of the distance, not all of it.

Comment: Half of the time carpooling, the other half public transit. -> Multi-Select. But selecting Driving for carpooling might imply I myself would drive which isn't the case.

Comment: In some jobs this is a combination of several.  Drive a to a metro (train) station, take that into the city, walk a mile to the office.

Answer (score 34):

I'm curious what percent of full time developers do contract work on the side, also how the contracting pay compares to their salary

Comment: Good question! I am eager to learn if contractors make more or less than pay-roll employees.

Comment: The hourly rate of contract work should be more than the hourly rate of a salaried employee. This is mainly because remote freelancers are monitored more than on-site workers, their work tends to be billed in hours rather than "as long as it takes", and freelancers often bill for less hours than they have actually done (due to underestimates or useful pro-bono work that they would struggle to charge for).

Answer (score 33):

For self-taught coders:
What according to you is the best resource that helps in learning a (new) technology?

1. Books
2. Videos
3. Documentation
4. Online Courses
5. Courses by Paid Institutions
6. Combination of these

Comment: You're missing documentation?

Comment: What about the elephant the room is in?

Comment: For those who don't understand the subtleties of the above comment: Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Script47 I don't think anyone uses documentation for the purpose of "learning" a new tech. They are only good for reference purpose, aren't they ? eg. assume you are starting out with java, and went straight away to javadocs. It would takes hell of one's time and patience to go through a single page

Comment: __1)__ A solid foundation __2)__ Knowing how to learn __3)__ A great mentor __4)__ Immersion

Comment: @drac_o I never took any Java course or formally learned Java, but I've occasionally written Java code after learning C#. The only thing I needed for that were the Java docs. Similar story for Matlab. I think once you "got" (imperative) programming, you can mostly learn languages solely based on a handful of syntax examples (for which you need none of the options listed) + docs for language and libraries.

Comment: This seriously depends on what you're learning. I find books to be the most helpful when learning a programming language or complicated framework, I find videos the most helpful when learning visual things like CSS or game programming.

Comment: I would not dismiss documentation, as some technologies/frameworks/libraries have their own well-written tutorials section, sometimes with links to the official API/reference documentation and how to use them. Learning to check the official documentation is an important skill.

Comment: @drac_o *'I don't think anyone uses documentation for the purpose of "learning" a new tech'* - and that's why so many SO newbies ask questions on trivial syntax errors or other simple mistakes which are solvable by reading the docs.

Comment: Boy, I learned HTML by reading the HTML 3.2 spec. Guess I'm nobody :(.

Comment: Sorta confirming what Max said: Personally, I learned C# this year by reading the documentation (from an embedded C background, though i did java/android 7+ years ago). I think you definitely need to have a basis in programming already to learn a new language just by reading the docs, but it can be done. Even then though, your shotgun approach to things in one language just don't make sense in another (eg, trying to use pointers in C#).

Comment: Should contain "Source Code". Not everything has learning resources for it, or they might be outdated. Going in and reading the code (in case of open source) is the best way to find out what's _really_ going on.

Comment: "Actually coding" is really missing, especially considering this is supposed to be for **self taught** coders.

Comment: @TomášZato You should be "actually coding" along with each of these answers.

Comment: Ironically mostly a list of college-educated resources. Maybe it's just me but the first thing I'd due to learning a new technology is to set it up (using docs if need be) and start writing tests.

Where is the line drawn on who is/isn't self-taught anyway?

Comment: @Greg This was specifically for self-taught programmers as about 70% of who took the 2016 survey told that they were self-taught [link](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2016#developer-profile-education)

Comment: @drac_o _69% of all developers tell us they are at least partly self-taught. (13% of respondents across the globe tell us they are only self-taught.)_  So the question is more "what resources do the partly self taught coders use" as the list you've given doesn't include self-taught programmers main learning method?

Comment: @Greg Mate, why are you so negatively obsessed with the self taught coders. If are so wanting to know the _learning method_  of wholly college graduates then you can straight away ask a question youself instead of bashing here, can't you?

Comment: @drac_o I'm just trying clarify, the question asked differs from your comments.
What do you mean by "Technology"; a library; a first language; another language? Whether or not a person has prior core coding knowledge will drastically change the question/answers.
Writing code & running tests is a common learning technique which isn't on the list.
By "self-taught" is the question asking the 13% "purely self-taught" or the 70% "partially self-taught"? This should be clarified in the question if it was not intended to target just the 13%.

Answer (score 32):

> Did contributing through the Question & Answers within Stack Overflow help you to scale up in your development career?
>
> - Yes, definitely
> - Yes, somewhat
> - Neutral
> - No, not really
> - No, not at all
> - Not sure
>
> If yes, how did contributing through Stack Overflow helped you to scale up in your development career?
>
> - Made you a better programmer.
> - You got a promotion.
> - You got a hike in your pay check.
> - Landed you with a better job.
> - Started your own organization.

Comment: "scale up in your career" in what sense?  Did it make you a better programmer?  Did it get you a promotion?  did it get your more money?  did it help you land a new job?

Comment: Strongly Agree, interview cracking tips

Comment: Has to be clarified if you mean SO alone or SO + the careers fluff job listing part of the site.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks for the points. Updated !!!

Comment: @Lundin Updated with more specifics.

Comment: There should also be a "Yes, initially" answer. Because while it helped me get my first internships my contributions to SO have decreased in value over time in terms of advancing my career (because workplace experience has replaced it).

Comment: - No, you were disciplined/fired for spending too much time on SO.

Answer (score 32):

How did you learn about your current job?

- Job listing site (such as Stack Overflow Jobs, Glassdoor, etc.)
- Job fair
- Contacted directly by a recruiter
- Contacted directly by a non-recruiter in the company (friend, acquaintance, etc.)
- I'm currently unemployed
- I'm currently self-employed
- more?

It would be interesting to segment these by experience level (which I assume would be gathered in another part of the survey).

Comment: Option suggestion: I got this job from an internship

Comment: I actually heard about my job through a social media post someone shared. (I don't know if that's a common enough occurrence to be a multiple choice.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic I like that. I got to an in-person interview after reading about the position in a Tweet.

Comment: @Ferrybig then maybe ask: How did you learn about the internship ?

Comment: A few other possibilities: 1) Heard about the job by word of mouth (not as a direct recruitment attempt), decided to apply 2) Was already interested in the company, looked for recruitment info myself, 3) Applied from a different position in the same company, 4) Employed as a result of some previous contact or unpaid work, 5) Grad student employed at their university (during or after)

Answer (score 28):

> Which of these factors influence your performance evaluation the most? Order the items from the most important to least important.
>
> - Quality of work (e.g. number of bugs)
> - Quantity of work (e.g. lines of code)
> - Speed of delivery (e.g. how quickly you finish given task)
> - Number of work hours you put in
> - Your relationship with your team/peers
> - Your relationship with your direct supervisor (manager/team lead)
> - Years of experience in the role

Honestly I'm not a fan of those "order these items from x to y" questions as they require quite a bit of mental wrestling, particularly as the number of options increase. So this question might also be worded as,

> Which of these factors influence your performance evaluation the most? Pick any three.

Comment: If number of bugs is a measure of quality, then not doing any work is the best way of having the best possible work quality. Seems like a really bad measure to me.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It is just an example, and besides, no one looks at any of these factors in isolation. Generally a lower number of bugs would indicate better quality than higher number of bugs.

Comment: @Nisarg You have softwares full of bug and softwares no one use.

Answer (score 27):

Website themes are constantly in flux. It would be interesting to see how developers view themes with regards to work and home.

> When using a website for work, would you prefer that it is themed

- With a colored background
- With a textured / pictured background
- With a light background
- With a dark background
- With support for both a dark and light scheme
- Don't care

> When using a website for personal use, would you prefer that it is themed

- With a colored background
- With a textured / pictured background
- With a light background
- With a dark background
- With support for both a dark and light scheme
- Don't care

Comment: I'd be interested what theme they prefer for stackoverflow/stack exchange sites

Comment: I like a dark theme because it doesn't blind you at night.

Comment: or additionally "With a '90s geocities theme" like stackoverflow did (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382111/announcing-the-stack-overflow-time-machine), I dont think I've had a less productive day

Comment: @maxshuty - I was hoping we could all just forget that happened. Like some sort of distortion in the space time continuity.

Answer (score 26):

How supportive is your employer about

- learning and skill improvement
- experimenting with new technology or technology outside the scope of your current assignment?
- (related) switching you to a role in a different technology?

**Options:**

1. Very supportive

   - e.g. sponsors tech books, subscriptions, trainings, tickets to community events; will let you schedule time for learning activities  during work hours.
2. Moderately supportive

   - provides some of these things.
3. Not very supportive

   - hesitant to provide these things, may eventually provide after some nudging
   - mentions cost concerns.
4. Not supportive at all

   - will not provide any of these.

**Alternative:** Question could also be phrased *'How much does your employer invest in ... ?'*

---

Would be interesting to see how the answers vary for junior and senior roles and number of years worked for that employer. E.g. the same employer being very supportive to a senior but hesitant with a newer junior developer.

Answer (score 24):

I wonder how often people do activities outside the office with their office colleagues without office sponsorship and not organized by company.

> How often are you doing activities outside the office with your office colleagues? (Not office-sponsored and not organized by company.)
>
> - Never
> - Once a week
> - 2-4 days in a week
> - Once a month
> - 2-4 days in a month
> - Once a year
> - 2-4 days in a year

Improvements to the question are welcome.

Comment: Perhaps clarify whether office-sponsored events, e.g. a "company picnic" or "holiday party" are included in this, or not?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @JonSchneider. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 23):

My original, simple idea:

> In the age of machine learning and AI, do you worry at all about your job being taken over by smart machines in the near future?
>
> - Yes
> - No
> - A little
> - Haven't given it much thought

---

---

As @Pikuni suggested, finding out why or why not developers are worried about about losing their place would be a lot more interesting and useful. There are three ways that I see of gathering this data:

Extending the options — Major downside: The reasons are likely many, and various. It would be very difficult to narrow them down to common options. Upside: Easy to process results.

Text box — Major downside: It will be difficult to extract the gathered data. Upside: A better reflection of what participants think

Best of both; extended options with an `other` option which opens a text box.

**Any suggestions on options for both yes and no answers?**

Comment: Though I agree with the question, I think it could be also interesting to know _why_ people worrry or not.

Comment: @Pikuni Do you mean what caused you to start worrying? I think it would be equally interesting to see why people are *not* worried.

Comment: Well, I meant to explicit reasons for your choice, but not specifically about the yes answer. Come to think of it, even the "Haven't given it much thought" option can have interesting "justification"

Comment: @Pikuni I wonder... the reasons behind it are probably very many and diverse (even subconscious), so maybe letting people explain in their own words would be more useful. Some questions before had an open text box. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, totally, I think an open text box would be interesting. It's not really easy to process as a survey result, but who knows, there could be a lot of people having the same justifications.

Comment: @Pikuni Or both, see edit.

Comment: I don't think that "other" would be useful.  Also, I don't think that what we actually want to know is *do they worry,* but *do they think their jobs will be taken over* by smart machines in the near future.  That can be answered "yes" or "no" and then a text box can be devoted to "why or why not."

Comment: Like a reverse Pascal's Wager, a rational person should answer "yes" or "a little", because it's not an unreasonable conclusion that AI may in our lifetimes be able to replace our work. Unless, of course, that person is multi-skilled outside of IT and would pick up an equally-satisfying job (and thus be able to answer "no" comfortably).

This question, at it's core, is asking "Would losing your career suck?".

Therefore, a better question would be "Do you believe AI will replace your job in your lifetime?".

Answer (score 22):

I believe, most of developers will love to have a project manager with both sound technological knowledge and great managerial skills. If your company can't provide you your desired manager, who will be your next ideal manager among the following options?

> If you had to work for a manager who isn't good with both technical skill and interpersonal/managerial skills, what skill/knowledge trade-off would you choose?
>
> - **Strong technical** knowledge but **poor managerial** skill
> - **Basic technical** knowledge and **basic managerial** skill
> - **Great managerial** skill but **technically unskilled**
> - **No manager** needed

Any improvement to my question is highly appreciated.

Comment: Similarly, it would be interesting to not only ask about desired coding knowledge, but what your current manager's coding knowledge is, as well.

Comment: Potential follow-up: How actively does he/she write programs? (Have they stopped programming altogether or do they still do it albeit somewhat less than before.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'required' here. Also _'What is X's coding knowledge?'_ doesn't sound right to me. _'How knowledgeable is X about coding?'_ sounds better IMO.

Comment: I wanted to know whether you prefer to have a manager with strong coding knowledge or less coding knowledge? But I think I could not phrase it correctly. Can you help me rephrase it correctly?

Comment: All else being equal, people would generally choose the top options over the bottom ones (knows *[only]* basics, tech illiterate). Maybe you should balance the options to represent tradeoffs: tech-illiterate *but* has amazing managerial skills.

Comment: The question could be simply phrased _'Who is your ideal project manager?'_. Maybe that changes your question but see my comment above. Otherwise, it could be _'What is the minimum coding proficiency you expect of your project manager?'_ with your options - they must be an active coder, can be tech illiterate etc.

Comment: @pius thank you for your valuable feedback. I have edited my question according to your feedback.

Comment: Ideally speaking, there is no need of managers if you are able to decipher the requirements, plan and deliver. And yes, that also involves co-operating and collaborating with people.

Comment: @MedImage I like your comment. I agree with you. I am putting another option. Thank you.

Comment: Sufficient technical knowledge, great managerial skill.

Comment: @scunliffe I didn't keep this option because I knew everyone will choose it.

Comment: I think the problem is that without sufficient answers (especially radio options only) is that you get invalid results (users forced to choose the least wrong of all the wrong answers). e.g. I've had managers across the spectrum. If a manager doesn't have half decent tech knowledge... it is **very** frustrating trying to communicate technical issues.  However a manager that doesn't understand mgmt and clearing roadblocks etc. is almost worse. I want someone strong in both, but I'll take half decent in tech over no tech any day of the week.

Comment: @scunliffe Generally most of the people will choose your option because it's most likely to be desired. Therefore I wanted to know which option they will peek if there is not a perfect fit.

Comment: @Roaim Considering your premise in the last few comments I've adjusted the question to be more accurate on what you're trying to gauge.

Answer (score 21):

> How would you rate development of SO?
>
> - -10 (was better before)
> - 0 (not sure)
> - +10 (very happy)
>
> What you like the most?
>
> __ (dropdown)
>
> What you dislike the most?
>
> __ (dropdown)

Someone has to dig a list of new features, here is an idea:

> - teams
> - jobs
> - welcoming
> - new post wizard
>
> ...

Comment: "Teams" and "Jobs" are not _features_, they are _products_. "welcoming" is not a feature either, although at least it applies to SO proper.

Comment: @yivi, what is your proposal? To remove them from list or to change word "feature"? Do you like the idea? What else can be added to a list to "love" or "hate"?

Comment: It depends. Do you want the question to be about SO related products, or about SO Q&A development and features. Those are distinct and different IMO.

Comment: @yivi, it would be nice to compare my answers with a certain group, e.g. to see if c# developers dislike jobs the most =D This kind of stuff. I guess it would also be interesting for SO developers. But I am unsure what should be put into list.

Comment: @yivi "Jobs" at least was pushed on the homepage and presented as a new feature of stackoverflow before they backed off a bit.  It definitely belongs in the list regardless of what it's called.

Comment: @Izkata I disagree. It's not a "feature", not for a long shot. It's a differentiated product. Like Teams. Or SO for Enterprise. But these are different products that different people use.

Comment: @yivi You're right, "welcoming" is not a feature. It's a bug.

Comment: Good question, but they will never include this in the survey because it would be too embarrassing and depressive for the company. On the other hand we probably lost some >10% of the user base this summer, so those most discontent might not even be taking the survey.

Comment: "was better before" what? When? Before the last equinox? Before the Unix epoch? Before 6 - 8 ___s ago?

Comment: "Are you happy with the passionate people helping SO become what it is today, be shoved off the edge?"

Answer (score 19):

Something that was a surprise when I transitioned to a programming position is how often people are "on-call" and how seriously teams treat this responsibility.

Obviously I'd prefer a job where I can sleep through the night, but maybe there aren't any in my country+industry+salary band. I'd appreciate a question like:

> Describe your team's on-call responsibilities:
>
> 1. We don't have an on-call rotation or cover after-hours calls.
> 2. We cover alerts only on the weekends
> 3. We cover alerts outside normal business hours, but business-hours alerts go through a standard help desk process.
> 4. We cover alerts all day and all night, including during business hours.

Comment: As someone who endures on-call responsibilities, may I make some changes to your listed options to (I think) improve them and perhaps raise this question in score?

Comment: Maybe something about whether you get notified first or if you are part of an escalation chain if the NOC or whatever can't handle it first

Comment: @TylerH Edit away!  Or drop them in the comments and @ me and I'll add them.

Comment: @JeremyWeirich Thanks; I made an adjustment based on what I think might be more broadly applicable -- feel free to roll back in full or in part if you disagree!

Answer (score 17):

Ask more about **problems and needs** rather than demographics and personal preferences. E.g.,

Which of the following problems do you repeatedly encounter:

- Low-quality code by colleagues
- Legacy code by long-time former colleagues
- Incompatible versions
- Too many libraries in one project
- Too many programming languages mixed
- Security issues from used libraries
- Security issues from custom code
- Dead libraries and companies' code still in use
- Dependencies change too fast, cannot keep up
- Scalability issues
- Parallelization issues
- Machine learning is required for, but does not work
- Too much hype
- ...

So that we get to know the threats and problems people notice.

Comment: There is never "Too many programming languages mixed" :D Mixing languages is fun

Comment: Maintenance hell is fun - if it's not you who has to suffer.

Answer (score 16):

Having recently shifted my work interest to AppSec, I'm interested in how developers/companies approach security, so:

How do you do security testing/auditing (mark all that apply)?

1. Use an automated tool as part of the build/CI/CD process
2. Manual code-review/pen-testing by an internal security expert
3. Manual code-review/pen-testing by an externally-contracted security expert
4. We don't, but I wish we did
5. We don't. My code is good, I don't need to worry about security

Comment: Also needs an: "We don't build software where security is an issue" option.

Comment: @BDL, perhaps when you develop a hourglass, but otherwise security should always be an issue.

Comment: @Luuklag: We, for example, are developing software for building simulations (mostly CFD stuff). All the data comes from other software packages and it's a desktop software. I really wouldn't know what security concerns there could be (unless protecting the input data, but as I said, that is not coming from our software).

Comment: Need to be able to select multiple options as depending on the industry you are in there will be automated tools as well as mandated manual testing by both internal and external sources to maintain certifications

Comment: Adjusted the last option to be less haughty and at the same time cover BDL (and my own) scenario.

Comment: @BDL AFAIK, DoS is part of the security of a piece of software, independently of where in the stack sits. If something we learned, is that every link in the chain has to be as secure as possible.

Comment: Seconding the "We don't build software where security is an issue" suggestion. Or maybe rephrase it as something like "I don't think security is relevant to the sort of work I do". Don't forget: not everyone answering the question will be a full-time developer for a software company. There are plenty of researchers, data scientists and similar people who only use code as a tool to do their actual job. How would you pentest a bunch of Tensorflow scripts? A Simulink model? A complicated spreadsheet? The "my code is good" option doesn't cover this, since it has different implications.

Answer (score 16):

> What are your personal red flags if you were to be interviewed for an IT-related work/position?
>
> - Question/s asked during interview
> - Test/s quality during interview
> - Behavior of the interviewer
> - Location of the interview
> - Position of the interviewer
> - Other options

Comment: Hard to answer this, because none of these *subjects* should be a red flag, but rather one or some of the *contents* of the subjects could be.

Comment: Will I be subject to a 'no-poaching agreement"

Comment: @TylerH Maybe a re-wording of the question or the more specific choices may make this answer better?

Comment: @CarlBinalla There are too many possible things that could apply to individuals; this would be better as a free-text response question, IMO.

Comment: I have a true red flag: a non-programmer doing the interview, or a person with complete lack of understanding of the field. I'd assume you got it covered under "position of the interviewer"?

Answer (score 15):

How many paid vacation days do you have per year?

I guess most of the civilized countries have paid vacation granted by legislation. However, good companies usually grant you a few more. This data grouped by country (and age) would be useful info not only for (soon to be) expats.

Comment: As you state, this answer might not be applicable to all kinds of developers; in the Nordic (European) countries, for instance, there are very strict laws on this topic.

Comment: @Andreas Why should it not be applicable? Apart from hobby coders I guess. Are there any upper boundaries in those Nordic countries?! If there are strict laws then at least you have a lower boundary. Maybe in a fictional totally planned out communist country you should be able to answer this question: "I, as every other worker in my country, have (say) 20 paid vacation days per year - our employers are not allowed to give us more."

Comment: mbx, You just described working laws in Brazil. Everyone gets exactly 30 paid days of vacation per year. In around 20 years in IT Industry, never heard someone who gets more or less than that (in IT or in any other working area). It's just the law and everyone follows it. Same goes for how much an extra hour should be paid, how many sick days and the list is long and goes on...

Comment: @gmauch Then that would be the answer. If you analyze the data, you then get some countries with x days, other countries with 0-y days and a nice distribution. Nothing wrong with that, the opposite in fact. That's exactly what I'd like to know (or any other dev, considering working in another country).

Comment: Ensure that there is an "unlimited" option. Some of us are very lucky to work for a company that enables you to take vacation as much as you like/need.

Comment: @scunliffe 366 should be enough then as the question is per year (considering gregorian calender, safe for most common calendars I hope). I somehow implied 1 Month with x hours per week as baseline which ain't true for a measurable subset. Nation wide holidays are another detail we might want to take into account. I guess we'll have to refine the question a bit and probably add some sub-questions.

Answer (score 14):

I'd like to see more thoughtful slicing of the data by *age*. For example:

- Programming language popularity by *age*
- Income by *age*
- Work status by *age*
- Those who've faced perceived discrimination due to age

When I read about 'representation', race, and gender in these results, I'm amazed that the second-largest group facing discrimination is ignored: people over  about 35. It's second only to racial discrimination, above gender. It's the (silent, insidious) elephant in the room, and given that the overwhelming majority of respondents last year were under 30 or so, you can see why. It isn't just 'older people chose not to respond'.

Comment: C, less than 18, no income, no work, possible discrimination

Answer (score 14):

I'd like some insight into hiring practices with respect to coding exercises. Possible wording might be:

- ### Are you more/less/unchnaged likely to accept a job if

or

- ### What is your reaction when asked to do the following during an interview/application process?

  1. I'm glad they asked! I think this is important!
  2. Meh, it's their interview, I'll do what they ask.
  3. This seems fishy, but I'll do it anyway.
  4. Red flag. I may not like this place.
  5. Deal breaker. I won't do it. End of interview.

With questions/scenarios such as:

1. Whiteboard coding
2. Live coding in a text editor (not an IDE, no test runs)
3. Live coding and debugging (i.e. running/testing your code as you go)
4. Unpaid programming assignment (on your own time, not live)
5. Paid programming assignment
6. Automated programming test on HackerRank or similar platform
7. Multiple-choice test about a particular programming language or platform

Comment: This question is extremely underrated IMO and should be taken into consideration

Answer (score 14):

The last time you voluntarily left a job (as opposed to being laid-off) it was because you were looking for:

1. Less overtime
2. Better compensation
3. Remote work
4. Clear objectives
5. More recognition for your accomplishments
6. A less toxic culture
7. A more ethical employer
8. More opportunities for growth
9. Better commute
10. I've never quit a job
11. n/a (e.g., you retired, or left for non-work-related reasons)

Comment: Consider also the option to leave a fixed-term employment contract before its end for a permanent one.

Comment: Voluntarily leaving and being laid off are not the only options. Other common termination reasons include: being fired, or a contract simply ending.

Answer (score 12):

> How would you want your office to look and feel like?
>
> 1. Casual and fun, while you can hang around and code on your laptop on comfy sofas and eat anytime, nice holidays.
> 2. Strict, you want to work and finish deadlines and go home ASAP with even nicer holidays
> 3. Neutral, you don't want it to be strict nor casual, just a workplace and early leave times.
> 4. An awesome workplace with every amenity and good friends but fewer holidays.
> 5. You’d rather work (remotely) from home than to prefer an office

This is something I'd give a thought before answering

Comment: 5. I work form home.

Comment: @aloisdg no, that is not the question. _How would you want your office to look and feel like?_

Comment: @weegee I think what he meant is that his answer would be "no office" ?

Comment: @MathieuVIALES well the question is about officesess not about homes, I’ll include it too anyways

Comment: @weegee Mathieu got it. I dont want to be in an office. Let me work wherever I want to be (my home, a coworking place, a boat, a plane, whatever). Just accept that I dont want to be in your corporate place. Look at my work not where I put my butt.

Comment: 5th one should be generalized to 'rather work remotely than ...'

Comment: Also, objective things like noise, physical isolation, team interaction matter more to me than subjective things: 'awesome workplace', 'fun', 'good friends'

Comment: Outside the USA, where other countries exist, holidays are most often regulated by law.

Comment: @Lundin wink, wink https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389605/303290

Answer (score 12):

Q: What public-facing "web presence" do you have as a developer, that you would want prospective employers to be aware of, to get a sense of who you are and what you can do?

- Profile on LinkedIn or a similar professional networking site
- Personal blog
- Articles posted to dev.to, Medium, or another shared blogging site
- Personal website
- Profile and public code on GitHub or other open-source code hosting site
- StackOverflow profile
- StackOverflow Developer Story
- Published open source project(s)
- Published commercial project(s)
- Twitter, Instagram, other other public-facing social media profile
- Profile on Pluralsight or a similar skill-assessment site
- Something else
- None of these

Comment: I would say that personal blog/website can be merged.

Comment: This should be a multi-select question (e.g. checkboxes, not radio buttons)... in case this gets used. There's also really a split between which of these mediums do you have vs. which do you want the employer to use. E.g. I have an Instagram account, but I would never want an employer to use that as my "resume" when considering me.

Answer (score 9):

In 2019, survey is carried out asking if developers are using containers ( `Using Containers`)

But personally think that survey should be carried out to find out which browser do developer prefer.

If Stack Overflow keeps tracks of which browser type they are getting request from 
then it can be used to display browser stats. (i.e. No need to carry out survey on browsers)

Which desktop browser do you prefer as primary browser?

```
1) Chrome
2) Chromium
3) Firefox
4) Opera
5) Tor Browser
6) Safari (OS Specific)
7) Microsoft Edge (OS Specific)
8) Internet Explorer (OS Specific)
9) Other
```

Suggestion on this - much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean to use for browsing or for development? I ask because I don't use a browser for development so the question would be meaningless for me if that's your intent.

Comment: Can't this question be answered already, just by looking at traffic stats?

Comment: @Flimzy not necessarily. Some people might be forced to use a different browser at work, or prefer to use a different browser for some websites. Also, Tor registers as Firefox. There's no real way to detect it without checking the IP, but unless they actively cache potential exit nodes, that might be an expensive operation. And with various forks off open-source browsers, Chromium and Firefox (and possibly others) might get unattributed share if you just look at the webkits. Just looking at traffic stats won't reveal preferred primary browsers.

Comment: I'm sure those variations are low enough in the noise, that the noise from human-provided answers will outweigh it. I think this question isn't meaningful. Even if there were an accurate way to ask this--what valuable insight would it provide?  (0.02% of people are forced to use a weird browser... so what?)

Comment: I am unable to answer this question, because I fully embrace two primary browsers: Safari and Firefox. Safari on my Mac, and Firefox on my Windows computer. Firefox has such good anti-tracking abilities, that even if it's not the primary browser on my Mac, it still ranks high (I sometimes use it on my Mac as well).

Comment: @Flimzy "Prefers" != "uses". One's primary browser may not be the one they use at work, but rather the one(s) preferred on one's personal computer(s). "Which desktop browser do you **prefer** as primary browser?"

Answer (score 9):

What tool do you generally use to log notes relating to your daily tasks? ( daily use work journal)

1. Professional note taking apps like Microsoft OneNote, EverNote etc
2. Notes added over standard HTML and rendered as static pages hosted on the company’s intranet.
3. Using Markdown syntax for logging notes and using Static Sites (GitBook, Hugo, Jekyll with GitHub pages) to host them.
4. Offline notes - Notepad (pen/paper)
5. I don’t take work related notes that often

Comment: Pen and paper is not an option?

Comment: @VLAZ: Offline notes - Notepad should cover that

Comment: More possible options: Plain .txt files? A private or internal wiki website? A personal "todo" app (e.g. Todoist)? Comments on the card/ticket/task itself in the team's ticketing system or Kanban board?

Answer (score 8):

**Q.1 for what reasons developers want to change their organization/company?**

- due to often overtime work
- no standard processes are followed in organization/company
- want to do freelancing/remote work
- expects more CTC/salary
- other

**Q.2 should traveling time consider in working hours?**

- yes
- no

Comment: Extra option for the travel time question: partly. I feel like my travel time should be compensated somewhat, but it's still my own fault I live far away from the office.

Comment: I don't think it's legal for most employees to require being paid for travel time (unless part of the job, and counted as working hours) in my country. I've never heard of any company paying for traveling to/from the office, here. I hear people complaining about 1.5 hours in traveling, per day, but the solution they "indirectly" propose, is to buy a house closer to their office. I'll be really surprised if people from my country would think it's a good idea letting traveling time be considered work time.

Comment: There should be some policy for traveling time compensated from which both people and company can get benefited

Comment: article on traveling time consider as working hour https://www.businessinsider.in/time-taken-to-reach-office-in-traffic-to-be-counted-as-office-hours-rules-a-european-court/articleshow/54380810.cms

Comment: I wonder if most companies have any idea why their developers leave. I wonder how many do know why but don't realize that they can do something about it and how much it would benefit them. If your company is a good place for developers to work, the benefits are not limited to retaining employees. They're probably getting a lot more done and with higher quality.

Answer (score 8):

> How often do you spend time on learning and self-development?

- Every day
- Twice or thrice a week
- Once a week
- Twice or thrice in a month
- Once a month
- Once in few months
- Once a year (seriously?!)

> How often does you boss / manager give infeasible deadlines?
>
> How often do you complete you job within infeasible deadlines?
>
> Do you feel stressed or excited when infeasible deadlines are given?

- I feel stressed, sometimes even frustrated
- I feed stressed, can't even sleep at night
- I feel excited and find the task challenging
- I don't feel anything, I ignore deadlines and complete the task with my own pace
- Other than mentioned above

Comment: You should add in an "Other" choice.

Comment: @MilkyWay90, yeah agreed! Done the change!

Answer (score 8):

What is your education level?

1. I never completed any formal education
2. Primary/elementary school
3. Secondary school
4. College/university study without earning a degree
5. Associate degree
6. Bachelor's degree
7. Master's degree
8. Professional degree
9. Doctoral degree

Comment: Isn't this, along with other "standard" demographics always, implicitly included?

Answer (score 8):

**What made you start programming?**

options:

1. School / study
2. Curiosity
3. Friends / parents
4. Requirement for job / study
5. Job possibilities
6. Money
7. To make an website / app
8. Hacking

These are just some initial options i could think of please feel free to add or to change them :)

Answer (score 8):

I would personally like to see a few questions on sleep habits:

1. On average, how many hours of sleep do you achieve on a given work night?
2. On average, what time do you usually try to go to sleep?
3. Do you use any form of sleep aid?

Answer (score 7):

Do you prefer a Dark theme or a Light theme for working?
I'm curious how many actually use a dark theme.

Comment: Very similar to [this other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389669/1364007)

Answer (score 6):

I am really curious about the state of salaries worldwide, to be more precise I have noticed that in my country (Mexico) a success measure is to be in USA, it is even a point of reference, last time we hired a guy that had amazed the whole team and with a huge name inside Mexican dev community, the reference was 'There are no guys who code like him in Mexico, they all have left for the USA'

Of course, the main reason to leave Mexico is to earn a salary in US Dollars, but with the rise of the remote job, I find it really hard for companies in Mexico to compete with foreign companies.

So my question would be something like `Do employers try to compete with salaries internationally, or just locally?`

When I have expressed this to recruiters they are all shock about my salary expectations so `Do local recruiters thing your salary expectations are too high?`

Answer (score 5):

> How many software development conferences did you attend in 2019?

or (to account for multi-day conferences)

> How many days did you spend on attending software development conferences in 2019?

Answer (score 5):

What environment do you work in?

- Open Office Plan
- Half Cubicle
- Full Cubicle
- Office
- Shared Office
- Co-working Space
- Home office

Which environment do you prefer to work in?

Answer (score 5):

How about something about mentoring? I think it is an important subject that has been undervalued.

```
Do you have a mentor in your job?

 1. No.
 2. Yes, informally.
 3. Yes, officially and I trust him.
 4. Yes, officially and unfortunatelly, since I don't trust him.
```

Answer (score 5):

> Do you suffer from back pain due to sitting for long hours in front of computer?
>
> If the answer to the above question was yes, which part of back hurts?

- Upper back
- Lower back

> How intense is the pain?

- Slight pain; can bear it
- Moderate pain
- High pain; can't bear it but somehow manage to continue to sit
- Lethal pain; can't bear it and can't continue to sit for long and have to get up for a walk

> How long do you sit in front of computer in one stretch?

- < 15 mins
- 15 mins - 30 mins
- 30 mins - 1 hr
- more than 1 hr

Comment: an alternative could be: "Do you have physical disorders that you attribute to the sedentary nature of computer work?" and a multiple choice answer with the most common problems such as back pain, headache, etc

Comment: @PaoloFulgoni, yes, that would be generic!

Answer (score 5):

> We're a bit short of moderators right now - would you like to be one?
>
> - Yes
> - No

Answer (score 4):

> Which one do you think whose quality affects your working / office experience the most?
>
> Assume all of them are available but only a few of them are of the top quality / performance, name your choices.
>
> - The computer itself (a fast CPU, abundant RAM, or a responsive SSD, etc., including network connectivity)
> - Monitor (Quantity / Layout / Looking experience)
> - Keyboard
> - Mouse
> - Audio devices (Headset, Earphones, Music stands, etc., also select this option if you want to say "a mic")
> - Sitting equipment (Chair / Sofa / Wheelchair)
> - Desk / Shelf / Drawer / Locker (Desk and its accessories)
> - Coffee machine or another drink provider
> - The lights in the office / Ambient illumination
> - Physical exercising equipment
> - Relaxing equipment (Bed, massaging chair, etc.)
> - Aids / Medical support department

This can be either a single choice, or multiple-choice with ordering.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer _always_ be "computer/keyboard/monitor" because without those, nothing else is relevant? A great mouse or audio system means nothing without a computer to plug it into.

Comment: @Flimzy My bad for not making the question clear. I was intended to ask something like a choice between "good computer + crappy keyboard" / "laggy computer + comfortable keyboard" or so.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to see some insight into which workflow "methodologies" developers most like or dislike. I'm not sure how best to word it to get meaningful results, but the key insights I'd like to receive are which methodologies devs find most useful, and perhaps most enjoyable.

Perhaps something like:

### For each of the following methodologies, which do you find helpful versus harmful?

Perhaps with a 1-5 scale (1 = very helpful, 5 = very harmful, 0 = no experience)

1. Traditional top-down project management
2. "Strict" Scrum (actually follows the Scrum guide, with dedicated scrum master, product owner, etc)
3. Kanban
4. DevOps
5. Scrumban (Scrum / Kanban mixture)
6. XP (Extreme Programming)
7. Agile, but with no specific methodology
8. No methodology at all.
9. Other [With free form field to specify?]

Should any others be on the list?

Comment: I'm sure there is a long tail of *9. Other (specify which) (use other side of paper if necessary)*

Answer (score 4):

I am curious about how many people plan their retirement!

```
 Did you plan your retirement? 
 when do you think you can take retirement from your work.

- Not planned 
- At age 35-45
- At Age 45-55
- After 55
- I don't want to retire
```

Any improvements to the wordings are welcome.

Comment: Retirement depends on the country in which you reside. In some people receive money from their government, in others they don't and have to plan something.

Comment: In those countries, does the government gives money if I retire today? if not just curios like till what age developers like to code or whether they plan to retire earlier(not waiting till the government recommended age of retirement)

Answer (score 4):

How often do you feel Imposter Syndrome?

1. Constantly
2. Often
3. Sometimes
4. Rarely
5. Never

Comment: Those who answer never "Never" should have a follow up question to assess the "Dunning–Kruger effect".

Comment: I'd be kind of hesitant to answer this one because I'm not sure if what I'm feeling is really imposter syndrome and I wouldn't want people to find out that I don't even know my own imposter syndrome feeling level.

Comment: Maybe this could be re-worded to be a little more general; I'm sure people would more likely to choose how they feel when asked something like "Do you feel that you don't deserve your position, and that you are inadequate, unqualified, etc, for it?" *Impostor Syndrome* sounds like a disease or mental health issue.

Answer (score 4):

Do you find the air conditioning in your office is:

- Too Warm
- Too cold
- Perfect
- I do not have air conditioning

What temperature is your Air condition set to?

`___`

Do you feel that the temperature of the office

- Aids your productivity
- Diminishes your productivity
- Has no impact on your productivity

Comment: Air conditioning what's that??... *sarcasm*

Answer (score 3):

> What profession would you choose if you couldn't work in software/IT? (free-text response).

Answer (score 3):

How often are you in the **flow** (or *zone*) during work?

- Every day
- A few times per week
- A few times per month
- Rarely
- Never

---

Note: definition of [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)) from Wikipedia:

> flow is characterized by complete absorption in what one does, and a resulting loss in one's sense of space and time

Comment: Perhaps "How often do you get interrupted during work?"

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ interesting question too, but quite different. not being interrupted doesn't mean being in the flow

Answer (score 3):

```
Do you participate in competitive programming such has Hackearth?
1) Yes, more than once a month
2) Yes, about once a month
3) Yes, once every few months
4) Yes, but only occasionally
5) No, never.
```

Answer (score 3):

Please spend some time and include the Delphi/ObjectPascal in the languages list at last. It's a shame you have overlooked it for several years prior

Answer (score 3):

How often you check your mobile / personal devices during work ?

1. Never
2. 15 minutes once
3. 30 minutes once
4. one hour once

Answer (score 2):

Given the choice, would you take a 20% pay cut to work a 4 day week?

Comment: Don't you always have this option?

Comment: @rekire that's up to your employer

Answer (score 2):

> **Open Source initiative** is widely growing and gathering more and more
>   evangeists and enthusiasts across the world. It brings not only
>   practical things, but also a cultue. As the poll auditory is highly
>   representative, it will be extremely interesting to find something out
>   about how far the community spreads. So ...

#### Do you contribute to Open Source community?

- I'm an active contributor in a **large-scale open source foudation** (Eclipse, Apache, etc)
- **maintain a project** which is expoited and has a community
- **participate** as an active member in an open source project, not as a maintainer
- occasionally **fix/improve libraries** I use for my projects
- run **a pet project**
- **do not** contribute

This is multy-choice selector.

Answer (score 2):

What was your last "simplification" (project technology/language/ or framework) and what did you move to?

Examples,

- Fortran to C++
- EJBs to Spring
- Java to python
- Adobe Flex to ReactJS
  ...

I think it is a practical hint about the direction industry is heading towards to know what employers are paying money for.

All suggestions to modify this question are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering how often people change companies/roles and what the motivations might be.
The survey already asks how long one has been working, so we can use that as a basis for the below.

First, we need to know if you're a freelancer/contractor.

> Are you a Freelancer / Contractor or a Permanent Employee?
>
> - Freelancer / Contractor
> - Permanent Employee

Company changes (since we have how long one has worked, we can either ask how many companies one has worked at, or how often they change companies):

> How many companies have you worked at in total? _____ companies.
>
> How long do you stay at a company on average?
>
> - Less Than A Year
> - 1 Year
> - 2 Years
> - 5 Years
> - 6+ Years

Reasons for changing companies:

> The reason you typically switch companies:
>
> - Better Total Remuneration
> - Better Travel Time / Commute
> - Better Role
> - Better Work Environment
> - Retrenchment / Job loss

Role Changes:

> How many times has your role changed in total? ____ times.
>
> How long do you keep a role on average?
>
> - Less Than A Year
> - 1 Year
> - 2 Years
> - 5 Years
> - 6+ Years
>
> Reasons for changing roles:
>
> - Promotion
> - Change in Area of Expertise (i.e. what you do day-to-day)
> - More Leadership aspects
> - More Technical Work

Answer (score 1):

How many computers/VMs do you work with, and what OS are they running. For example, 1 windows, 2 Linux VMs and 3 remote Linux servers

Answer (score 1):

- How engaged are you personally in mentoring efforts both within and outside your company?
- How engaged are you personally in diversity and inclusion initiatives both within and outside your company?

Answer (score 1):

How about the struggles faced by old developers?

- find my development job easy to manage
- I find my development job tough these days
- I am facing discrimination from my work place
- Not getting enough oppurtunities

Like the hard to speak to the world kind of questions, only for older developers.

Answer (score 1):

```
When does you worry about accessibility and friendly interfaces for people with 
disabilities in your projects?

 - Never
 - Only when explicitly said to implement it
 - When I have sparing time to do so
 - On the majority of the projects
 - In every single project
```

Even with people with blindness and low vision being roughly 285 million people across the world ([source](https://www.who.int/blindness/GLOBALDATAFINALforweb.pdf)), around 4% of the mankind, we have some [accessibility focused profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3825084/xle-22?tab=answers) that doesn't get a lot of recognition, what makes me wonder if the developers around here tend to implement accessibility in their projects as a must-do.

Answer (score 1):

Do you work on any other freelance projects outside work

Answer (score 0):

Serious:

> 1. Have advancements in development tools improved your productivity compared to a year ago?
> 2. How often do you check social media during working hours?
> 3. Are you concerned about your position being replaced by AI?

---

Silly:

> Which is a better pet, cats or dogs?

Comment: Didn't we already had the cats vs dogs questions in the survey of 2018?

Comment: I think question number 3 is waste of time. There are so many jobs to automate in the world and programming seems to be last of them. If anything add a timeline: "in 20/50/100 years?"

Comment: @kukis Really? I know someone involved in a project which has almost completed development of neural nets to create business applications from start to finish, code, dbs, and all. I think that the dev world might get a rude awakening.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I wouldn't be surprised if we already did the cat/dog one.

Comment: You are missing out on the best pet of them all, a Roomba

Comment: @TineO Yeah, those clean up after themselves.

Comment: I think #1 is too broad. A single bug fix in a tool you use could make the answer "yes", without providing useful information.

Comment: I don't think anybody can answer #2 reliably, unless they know the answer is "never"

Answer (score 0):

I am very curious and interested to learning following question from the community:

**Q1:** What makes you consider changing job and what matters most. Select 1 to 4 (1 is highest priority and 4 is least priority) Assuming that you do not have trouble, issues or problem with your company or your boss?

1. **Salary**, get higher salary than your current job.
2. **Learning**, what you learn and if your employer allows you to learn and improve your skills.
3. **Prestigious**, what you do and who you work for.
4. **People**, who you meet and work with.

**Q2:** In your job you do stuff that getting routine over time, what do you do to learn and improve your skills?

1. Routine does not bother you
2. You spend every weekend to learn and improve your skills
3. You spend once a month to learn and improve your skills
4. Where needed to learn and improve your skills

Comment: I think this needs to be made more specific, because motivations change over time and per circumstance. Such as, what factors when in to choosing to leave your last job. One may leave because of a bad boss in one situation, but for more money in another. There's probably rarely if ever a "general" answer here.

Comment: @Flimzy I agree with you, I assume the person do not have troubles with boss and the company in general, but want to take the next step in his/her carrier.

Answer (score 0):

Does your company use [hot desking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_desking)?

- Yes
- No

Comment: Curious - what's a hot desk?

Comment: @Adam I think it means that a there are no "set" workplaces, just a bunch of tables/chairs and connection points for electricity/network. Every day you come in and try to find a place to work, and hope there is one for you. I've only seen it used for external consultants, and it wasn't pleasant (for some reason, there is always one network cable _less_ than what would be need, there is squeaky chair that does the rounds around the office because nobody wants it, stuff like that). (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_desking)

Comment: @yivi you have described my daily morning routine hahaha

Comment: @AdamLear it is the desk that is still warm from the last person using it : )

Comment: How my. I wont even consider working in an office like this. Add this as possible answer and you have my vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some questions to learn about what kind of working space people like.

What office environment you like?
1) open environment where anyone can sit anywhere
2) One table where the entire team sits on a single open table
3) quite close ( table with some partitions between)
4) cubicles with own personal space.

And also how many developers are really into competitive programming & they want to increase their knowledge, combining this with age & years of experience can help in analyzing users eager to improve their skills.

Do you participate in competitive programming such has Hackearth/hackerRank?
1) Yes, more than once a month
2) Yes, about once a month
3) Yes, once every few months
4) Yes, but only occasionally
5) No, never.

Answer (score 0):

3 questions from me(they can be asked separately or updated if needed):

**Question 1**

> Do you do something special for your health(physical or mental)?
>
> - never
> - daily
> - weekly
> - monthly
> - I tried once

**Question 2**

> Do you have distraction free work and how many hours per day:
>
> - 0
> - 1 - 3
> - 3 - 5
> - 8

**Question 3**

> Do you meditate or do other similar practices and how often :
>
> - never
> - daily
> - weekly
> - I tried once

I'm interested in general data related to mental health.

Answer (score -1):

What Continuous Integration tool do you use:

- **Buddy**
- **CircleCI**
- **Drone**
- **GitLab CI**
- **GoCD**
- **Jenkins**
- **TeamCity**
- **Travis CI**
- *other*
- *none*

Comment: While I don't necessarily think this question should make the poll, downvoters care to give your opinions on why you made this decision?

Answer (score -1):

I would like to know, and I believe it will also be interesting for most of us to learn:

- How open is your organization to sponsor education fees? (for any position that requires programming knowledge)

  - Only managers can apply
  - Only specific positions can apply
  - Only trainees can apply
  - Anyone can apply
  - My organization does not sponsor any educaction fee.
- What is the % of the total fee your organization sponsors? (rounded to the nearest)

  - N/A
  - <20%
  - 20%
  - 40%
  - 50%
  - 60%
  - 80%
  - 100%
- Up to what level of education does your organization sponsor?

  - N/A
  - Undergraduate
  - Postgraduate Certifications/Diploma
  - Master's degree
  - Doctoral's degree
  - Post Doctoral's degree
- What's the modal interval for the age of employees benefiting from the sponsor?

  - N/A
  - 18-25
  - 25-32
  - 32-40
  - 40-50
  - 50-65
  - 65+

Answer (score -1):

It would be really hard to analyze it, because you create bias by making a selection beforehand, but it's near impossible to analyze if you don't.

But anyway.

> What hype would you like to see disappear as soon as possible?

And positively:

> What hype would you like to see become standard practice.

Not native speaker, so wording could probably better.

There's always been something in the survey about most dreaded technologies. Last year suddenly blockchain popped up. As our world in constantly in flux, I would really like to see what hypes we all notice and which ones we think are really bad and which ones are really good. Though it would be hard to analyze if you don't make a selection first...

Answer (score -1):

How much of your time at work do you spend on automating recurring tasks for yourself or your team? Where the recurring task itself is not part of the product you are shipping or the service you are providing.

- {n} hours per week

Answer (score -1):

How does reading questions and answers on SO affect you?

1. Positively, I learn new skills, expand my knowledge or feel valued for sharing
2. Good, I may pick up new items or enjoy sharing what I know
3. Indifferent
4. Poor, I feel overwhelmed / inexperienced / have nothing to share
5. Negatively, it makes me feel stupid / incompetent / unworthy to share

Answer (score -1):

Instead of asking for their first, or favorite language; maybe you could ask for the **order** in which they learned them, and in what **order they wish** they'd learned them (now knowing all the pros and cons of each one).

I've always wondered whether the path I'm taking is the best path from a beginner's point of view; and having professional developers give their opinion on this matter might generate interesting results. I imagine the optimal "path" for climbing the programming ladder, would be the one which the least amount of people regretted taking.

Answer (score -1):

Questions for developers who works in **outsourcing companies**. There are a lot of developers working inside of outsourcing companies that the IT is not his main activity and many of them had complains about it:

1. Do you have the right equipaments to do your job?

   - Yes, my company provides
   - Yes, the outsourcing company provides
   - No, I bought them
   - No
2. Your manager/company is able to follow your work in the client company?

   - Yes, we have periodical meetings
   - No
   - No, we just talk when some problem happens
3. How was your experience working with developers from other companies on the same project?

   - I never worked on this situation
   - Good, nothing really changes
   - Bad, there are situations where one company wants to look better than another
   - Bad, differences in development culture created many conflicts
4. How do you feel working outsourcing?

   - I like it
   - It's OK
   - Could be a lot better
   - I hate it

This is just some ideas. I will be glad if other people think on more questions on this subject.

Answer (score -2):

What about tech-level across your company. I've seen that companies where managers have deep technical experience, produce much higher quality products than companies that not.

```
Which of the following consistently represents the average technical skills of the management chain at the company you work for?
 A) Highly skilled 
 B) Just enough skilled
 C) Under skilled
 D) Not skilled at all

Do you consider the technical quality of your company's products is positively or negatively affected/influenced by the technical skillness of your management chain? 
 A) Yes
 B) No
```

Answer (score -2):

Being a coder/programmer have you thought about starting a startup company.?

1. Yes, I thought about it.
2. No, I never thought about it.

Comment: Add more granular options, maybe? As written, every one of "Yes, it crossed my mind briefly while I was having breakfast the other day", "Yes, I did a lot of research into it and built a working prototype but ultimately decided not to pursue it", and "Yes, I did found my own startup and had a successful exit for $10M!" would all fall under option 1.

Answer (score -3):

> Where do you put the opening curly brackets ?
>
> - On a new line, aligned with the closing one
> - On the same line than the scope declaration (function, condition, loop...)
> - I code in python

Comment: There are also many reasonable styles that do things different for e.g. functions vs loops. I have doubts that this question can be asked in a way that is detailed enough while still remaining meaningful.

Comment: It also depends on the language. JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion rules mean that certain forms for curly bracket inclusion just don't work well...

Answer (score -3):

> What industry do you dream/want to work in? (Select your current one
>   if it is your best preference.)

Answer (score -3):

Two independent questions:

```
How do you typically land into Stackoverflow?
  a) Through its home page
  b) Through a search result on Google
  c) By its mobile app
  d) Other

How do you search through Stackoverflow?
 a) Using Stackoverflow's built-in search
 b) Using external search like Google, DuckDuckGo or other
```

Comment: I would have to answer a & b for both of those, I think this should probably be a multiple choice format.

Comment: I think they already have this information.

Answer (score -3):

I would like questions about operating system use, specifically breakdown by Linux distribution

Answer (score -3):

What do you love most to do in free time <strike>office hours</strike>?

> 1. Chatting with a significant other/friends?
> 2. Talking with colleagues.
> 3. **To Q/A on Stackoverflow**
> 4. To search something new to learn
> 5. Sleeping on desk

Comment: What is this "free time" during office hour you're talking about? :)

Comment: :P So many reasons, you may didn't get webservices on time, you may have completed your task before the time, you may getting time in between doing programming. Event **free 5 minute** matters to do any above options. Specially I am doing Stackoverflow stuffs.

Comment: I guess you mean ["My code's compiling"](https://www.xkcd.com/303/)?

Answer (score -3):

How much time do you spend daily on Stack Overflow?

1. < 1h
2. 1h
3. 2h-3h
4. 3h-5h
5. 5h <
6. Half a day
7. The entire day
8. 25h
9. What's Life?

Answer (score -3):

How many hours a week do you spend persuading (or arguing)?

I personally have found that in some shops, the acts of programming, designing, and educating can take a back seat to defending and promoting ideas.  While not all shops get stuck in bickering, having semi-recently seen a shop where bickering is about 70% of the workday, I'm wondering if it is a common occurrence (and I've been mostly blessed with it's absence)

Answer (score -3):

This question is "aimed" mainly for full-time employees, but in my opinion, it can be relevant for every person who is about to start a "full day of coding".

1) Before you go to work, do you have any special and **fixed** morning routine, which lasts for ~30-45 minutes (the duration is "flexible" and can last a little longer or can be shorter) such as:

```
1. Eating a good breakfast at home/work.
2. Doing meditation.
3. Practicing mindfulness.
4. Yoga.
5. Workout (Run, GYM, etc...)
6. Other (fill in)
```

2) Do you find this morning routine beneficial for your productivity/focus during your working day?

```
1. Yes, without this morning routing I'm very much less productive/focused throughout the day.
2. Yes, without this morning routing I'm less productive/focused throughout the day.
3. No, with or without this morning routine my productivity/focused is more or less the same.
4. No, this morning routine is relevant also for non-working days.
```

Answer (score -3):

Do you travel for your job (monthly time frame)?

1. No Travel but work onsite
2. No Travel but work onsite with 1-3 days remote.
3. No Travel but work remote.
4. 25% Travel - 75% remote.
5. 50% Travel - 50% remote.
6. 75% Travel - 25% remote.

---

Are you considered

1. Salaried - Full Time
2. Contract W2 - Full Time
3. Contract 1099 - Full Time
4. Contract W2 - Part Time 1- many contracts
5. Contract 1099 - Part Time 1-many contracts
6. Contract 1099 and W2 - 1 to many contracts
7. Salary and W2/1099 Part Time 1- many contracts

Comment: What is 1099 or W2? Guess it's some US code?

Comment: It is what type of taxes do you pay an individual to work in the US. If you do contract programming in the US or you're salaried individual you can be with considered a W-2taxed individual or if one does direct contractor with a company it can be a 1099 which requires you to pay more taxes. It would be a USA only question I surmise

Comment: If I remember correctly from last year, there are no questions that are only asked to people of specific countries. I guess you will also see a lot of downvotes from non-US people who think that the question is not interesting (for them). Maybe you can try to reformulate it in a way that it can be answered worldwide?

Answer (score -3):

With the [advancements](https://www.i-programmer.info/news/90-tools/13074-kite-ai-powered-auto-completion-for-python.html) of code completion tools,

1- Would you consider a voice enabled IDE to be your main coding/debugging IDE?

- Yes
- No
- Maybe/I don't know
- It depends
- Other

2- Answered in free form, What feature (or multiple features) would make you consider doing the switch from your IDE to voice enabled IDE?

*Examples below*

- Code completion/modification (10> lines at a time)
- Integration with resources (e.g. StackOverflow, GitHub...) to resolve bugs (e.g suggested solution1, suggested solution2).
- Smarter troubleshooting (understands infrastructure where/how code is running)
- Giving a quality architectural suggestions (**hello Alexa** "o*r google/whatever. no bias or affiliation with any*", **let's start refactoring this monolithic app into smaller apps and modules. We will use few different languages based on where/how they are used today...**)

Answer (score -4):

I am interested to find out how programmers in general see themselves, and how this changes from hobbyists to students, and to professional developers.

**Important note: it is the idea which I am proposing; the options below are merely to illustrate my meaning.**

> As a programmer, how do you see yourself? Choose all that apply:
>
> - Geek
> - Normal person
> - Programming is my career/hobby, not part of my personality
> - It boosts my status a little
> - Part of the worldwide programming community
> - Different to those around me
> - Nerd
> - Gifted
> - Just someone who codes
> - A loner
> - Privileged

These are just a few things off the top of my head; please feel free to suggest/add more (also to remove the less relevant/important ones). I think we could learn something interesting from the resulting data.

Comment: Aren't geek and nerd synonymous?

Comment: @Lundin I'd say no, for me at least, geek is more computer savvy while nerd is more comic book fan

Comment: @Lundin Maybe yes, maybe not. Search "difference between a geek and a nerd" and you will have enough material for a masters thesis : )

Comment: @hat Sounds like a nerdy topic to study.

Comment: @Lundin Oh well, pandora's box has been opened https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Tvy_Pbe5NA

Answer (score -4):

I'd like to see some questions around your hiring practices and developer involvement. Do developers write code in your interview? On a white board? On a computer? Before hand? Are you satisfied with how the process works? Does the ultimate decision rest with the would be hires peers or superiors?

Answer (score -4):

I'm interested in what keyboard layouts people use, and how they type:

```
Which keyboard layout do you use?

- QWERTY
- DVORAK
- AZERTY
- COLEMAK
- Other/non-latin keyoard
```

```
How fast do you type?
[   ] wpm
```

```
When typing on a phone:

- I type with one hand, one thumb
- I type with two hands, both thumbs
- I hunt and peck
- I swipe
- Other
```

Comment: Isn't the choice of keyboards highly influenced by the country you live in? I am not sure that a lot of people actually _choose_ a keyboard, except if they come from another country using another type of keyboard than the one used in their original country... But I might be wrong about that. :)

Comment: Some people choose keyboards like DVORAK, or COLEMAK.

Comment: Oh, OK. :) I did not know about that. But then I think that there's a strong difference between choosing DVORAK instead QWERTY, for instance, and using AZERTY instead of QWERTY because is the norm in your country (as in France, for example). In one case, it's a layout preference from the user, while in the other, it's just two differents standards

Comment: *"When typing on a phone"* many people swipe-type too

Comment: I doubt many people know how many words per minute they can type.

Comment: Perhaps rephrase as: "Did you explicitly choose a specific keyboard layout for programming or do you prefer your countries/locales default keyboard layout?" default, dvorak, neo, neo2, colemak, ... there are lots of them, so maybe letting people name their layout (if not default) could be the best choice. Statistics is no fun with extremely low probabilities.

Comment: I would definitely like to see the question of how fast you typed, potentially linked to a speed test if people don't know off hand.

As someone that uses a non default keyboard (Dvorak) I'd love to know how alone I am, but at minimum the question needs two others, one for another more esoteric optimized layout, and one for a different regional layout.

Answer (score -4):

I would love to get some analytics on:

> Are you right-handed or left-handed?

Comment: Cross-dominant? Ambi-dextrous? And in any case, relevance? What is this useful for?

Comment: @yivi I didn't think about it until you asked but maybe you can get some info on workplace ergonomics for left-handed people! I posted suggestion since Anita did mention in her question `We are always on the lookout for fun/silly questions`.

Answer (score -4):

Have you been interviewed for the position with the latest technologies but after joining the company you were given a project which uses outdated technologies?

Answer (score -4):

> Do you teach the art of coding to your children?
>
> - Yes, with code.org
> - Yes, with scratch
> - Yes, with others
> - No
> - Certainly not, I don't want to pervert them
> - I don't have any children of a suitable age

Comment: 1) What's the difference between "No" and "Certainly not?", 2) Probably needs a few more options besides code.org (or don't mention it either), otherwise the question feels like an ad, 3) Obvious missing option "I don't have any children of a suitable age"

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker They carry a different sentiment. "no" has a "weaker" meaning than "certainly not". The first could imply that they haven't thought about or just haven't seen the point, while the latter asserts a strong opinion regarding the reason not to.

Answer (score -5):

> How ergonomic are you? / How ergonomic do you want your workstation to be?
>
> - Mouse
> - Keyboard
> - Posture?
> - Monitor
> - Chair
> - ...
> - Not at all
> - Whatever is provided

Not sure about the wording of the question, but you get the meaning.

Answer (score -5):

At your professional work, what percentage of your development is recognized as 'uniquely yours' means no other developer could easily lay hands on?
1. 0% 2. < 10% 3. < 25% 4. < 50% 5. >50%

At your professional work, what percentage of your development is recognized as 'previously impossible' means the company had failed to develop before with other developers, even after resorting to external consultants and specialists?
1. 0% 2. < 10% 3. < 25% 4. < 50% 5. >50%

Answer (score -6):

How often do you get your own desk; select as many as apply:

- It depends when I get in
- I'm on a rotating list
- I have to find my own desk at least once a week
- I have a permanent desk
- I work from home
- I don't need a desk at my job

(did I miss any?)

Comment: That's an interesting question... I've never heard of a workspace where you DON'T get your own desk, unless you mostly work remote. Is that common in your country? (i work in US/Canada)

Comment: @yhyrcanus lots of different teams, not enough room for everyone, but never at capacity....

Comment: @yhyrcanus The first three options all fit an open-floor-plan office, depending on how full it is and how they choose to mitigate it.  In fact, I'd add another:  one of our teammembers has given up and claims a stool/countertop in the kitchen instead of trying to get a desk.  I'm curious as to why this is so downvoted.

Comment: @Izkata I have all the first three and I'm not in a 'true' open plan office. We have small dividers between groups. Check the edit history for the reason it's downvoted...

Answer (score -6):

Last time round when I answered the question about whether we used unit tests where I work, I had to answer that we did not.  However, that is the main reason why I had moved to a different employer by the time the results came out.  (So nice to be back among the sane.)  I think it would be worth asking how developers feel about the answers to their questions -- after a question about something like whether tests are used you could ask another question like "How happy are you with the level of testing in use where you work?", with options like "I really want this to change", "I would quite like this to change", "I'm not bothered", "I think this is OK", "I feel strongly that we've got it right".

Answer (score -6):

> *1)* As a consultant, how often are you asked/incentivized/constrained to write dirty codes, e.g. spaghetti, undocumented, untested? *(an answer ranging from never to always).*

Somewhat equivalent question:

> How much/often is the quality of the code valued by your clients?

and

> *2)* As a consultant, how appropriately selected do you think the local "IT" guy is to evaluate your service ? *(an answer ranging from "not at all" to "perfectly")*.

Comment: Why would an IT guy evaluate my work?

Comment: @CrisLuengo After 5 years as consultant developping economic oriented tools, beyond "why", I can tell that 80% of the time, I had to interact with, and, ultimately be judged by, intra-companies' IT guies who knew nothing about coding beyond producing imperative spaghetti codes. And they were consulted by their hierarchy to know how good was my work, yet which was unit-test driven, documented and OO. The point is that they were not capable of apprehending be it 20% of the quality of the work that I was producing. This may be something specific to the economic modelling community though.

Comment: LOL. Is that because *it's "computers"*? I guess I've never been hired by someone who doesn't understand at least a bit about what I do.

Comment: @Cris whilst not going quite that far, they were simply more into clicking than into coding... coding 100% S.T.U.P.I.D codes, which according to them was enough to be qualified as a "programmer" and feel legitimate to judge others' codes, and enable (or not) the payment of contracts. As you say, lol.

Answer (score -6):

After all these decades of programmers being taught how to write proper programs, I'd like to know:

- **What percentage of your code contains useful comments?**

In most production code that I've seen, less than 2% of the source lines are useful comments. I've worked on projects with 5,000-line source files having zero comments.

Discussion should *not* include pithy assertions about so-called 'self-documenting code'.

Comment: I think it's very difficult to give an objective judgement to our own comments... everybody thinks their comments are useful :-)

Comment: @PaoloFulgoni - But I've seen far too much code with *no* comments.

Answer (score -7):

> How aligned to the current political situation in your country, are you? If you had the opportunity and option to, with minimal negative consequences, would you move to another country?
>
> - Yes
> - No

Would be interesting to see the statistics on this, preferably with a map that the countries with a higher percentage "yes" on this question, stand out.

Comment: I could see one on political slant maybe :)

Answer (score -7):

I'd like to know if people get paid enough money **for a family** (rent a house with enough bedrooms, pay schools, feed several mouths, etc) when offered country relocation. I've seen that it's usually the same salary a single person would get (which is fair in all terms, but it's a good reason not to relocate if your family would get an inferior or insufficient quality of life). So:

> After relocating to a different country for accepting a job offer, and
>   having lived there for a couple of years, was the initial  salary
>   offer worth enough to feed a family of 3-4 persons?

Comment: Very specific on one hand. It only applies to a very small subset of users. Extremely opinionated on the other (what's "enough to feed a family" equivalent to?).

Comment: There's a lack of developers in the industry. Each time more and more companies choose to perform recruiting to bring talent from other countries, just to fulfill their needs. The text could be rephrased, but the intention is this: "have you naively accepted a job offer on another country, to then find out you left everything just to decrease your quality of life?"

Comment: This question has so many assumptions that it would need many different "no" answers to be useful: No, I don't have a family to feed. No, I have never relocated to a different country. No, I have never accepted a job offer. No, I never lived there for a couple of years. No, they did pay me enough. Etc.

Answer (score -7):

## Question

You've been assigned to maintain the source-code of this software, what are you gonna do?

## Options

- The existing software is still alpha-tested level, I'm better off building a new one from scratch
- The existing software is still alpha-tested level, I'm gonna just keep on improving it
- The existing software is still beta-tested level, I'm still better off building a new one from scratch
- The existing software is still beta-tested level, I'm gonna just keep on improving it
- The existing software is super production-grade level, I'm still better off building a new one from scratch
- The existing software is super production-grade level, I'm gonna just keep on improving it as much as I can
- The existing software is super production-grade level, I'm gonna just keep it as it is with very minimal changes

The options are checkboxes where they can tick what works for them (developers)

Comment: On this question, voting indicates if you want to see this question in the survey or not.

Answer (score -7):

In 2019 Survey, .NET and .NET Core were two different option for framework section. Please merge these two into one as in upcoming recent future Microsoft is going to merge .NET Core and .NET Framework into one .NET.

Answer (score -8):

What is your MBTI type?

My guess would be a heavy skew towards Introverts, and Thinkers, with a moderate preference to Intuitives and a mix of Judgers / Perceivers.

Answer (score -9):

I would be interested to see the correlation between years of experience or job position (junior, senior, manager etc) and knowing about terms like:

- Technical Debt
- Cargo Cult Engineering
- Bikeshedding
- Conway's law

The question could be quite simple, for example *"Do you know what Technical Debt is?"* or another idea would be to add a humorous comic strip and ask the user if they get it. For example:

> ### Q: Do you understand what the following comic tries to say?
>
> [image]
>
> - Yes, I know what "Technical Debt" is
> - No, I will have to search for that

Comment: If you ask the question similar to the example, the result is heavily biased. The text (**of course** I know) and the setting in general make it seem as if every programmer have to know about those terms. But this will lead to a lot of people saying yes just because they think they should not, not because they do know.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @BDL. I removed the "**of course**" part. If you have any suggestions how to make the question better, please share.

Comment: Not using comic strip to avoid the "only male" stereotype ? (on top of the reputation the author has)

Comment: Yes, it can be replaced with something else ([this](https://twitter.com/ismonkeyuser/status/1044467413948002307) for example). I'm not focusing on this though or how the actual question is formed. The topics mentioned are the important IMHO.

Comment: Nice question but little refinement needed based on comments by far.

Answer (score -9):

How do you overcome a depression / burn out?

```
Nothing
Music (specify genre)
Vacations
Family support
etc ...
```

Answer (score -9):

To show the world that the stereotype of programmers/hackers is wrong:

- How many of you are wearing hoodies 24/7?
- Are you coding in VERY dark environments?
- Do you use multiple terminals?
- And most important: is your terminal theme green text on black?

Maybe also interesting would be the following:

- Do you have a nerdy partner (gf/bf)
- Do you just eat pizza?
- When was the last time you were going out of the house:

  - today
  - yesterday
  - this week
  - this month
  - this year
  - what's this outside you are talking about?

Comment: Those are stereotypes of programmers?

Comment: At least I had to deal with them...

Answer (score -9):

What Tech stack do you use at work?

Frontend:

Backend:

Database(s):

Hosting:

Comment: Not every developer builds web pages.

Answer (score -9):

In your opinion, which language will become *THE language* of the near future? (choice of N in M languages)

By *THE language* I understand a language that is widely used, such as JavaScript, Java and Python today, C not that long ago and COBOL... pretty long ago.

Answer (score -10):

There were two recent threads on lobste.rs which asked (to paraphrase):

1. [Name one thing you like about a programming language you hate](https://lobste.rs/s/hib1ui/say_something_nice_about_programming).
2. [Name one thing you hate about a programming language you love](https://lobste.rs/s/2cw6ov/say_something_you_dislike_about_language).

I think something like this would be really enlightening on this site.

Comment: I like this idea, but since it's not multiple choice, it would be hard to pull statistics out of it.

Answer (score -10):

Best conference talk you saw during last year?

Answer (score -11):

To answer a question on Stackoverflow, which resources do You use [multiple choice]:

- experience
- official standards
- official documentation
- blog posts
- books
- knowledgeable people around me
- ...

Comment: - Stack Overflow

Answer (score -11):

Challenging the ***mythical 10-lines per developer per day***:

> If we wish to count lines of code, we should not regard them as "lines produced" but as "lines spent". - Edsger Dijkstra

**I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966800/mythical-man-month-10-lines-per-developer-day-how-close-on-large-projects) question on Stack Overflow** and thought we could measure it by numbers instead of theories/opinions.

For an active project that your team is working on:

1. How many lines of code are changed weekly per developer on your team?
2. How many total [lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881441/can-you-get-the-number-of-lines-of-code-from-a-github-repository) are there in the project?
3. What language(s) do you use for this project?

**To narrow the field of this survey, here are some additional conditions:**

1. Project is in steady state, not in design, refactoring, or starting phases.
2. Project is not in an idle state, waiting for simplification or decommissioning.
3. Features are being added to the project.
4. Project is running in a production environment.
5. Take the average of 3 weeks, or use your best judgment.

Comment: Most survey questions tend to be something you can spend a few seconds / minutes on answering, this seems like it would take quite a while to get statistics on. There are probably also some organisations where individual developers don't have access to all aspects of a project.

Comment: PeterJ, Thank you, that makes sense. Any suggestions of how this survey can be modified?

Comment: I am thinking, delete Q2, make Q1 about the developer her/himself (instead of  the whole team) and for last working day (instead of last 2-3 weeks). Would that help making it acceptable?

Answer (score -12):

It would be interesting to know why coders became coders.

If free text questions are allowed, I'd like to suggest:

> Why did you start coding?

Comment: Not sure about that, as not too many good statistics could easily be made from this.

Comment: prefer multiple choice...

Answer (score -12):

#### Are you a human or a bot?

- Please select all the images with an upside down tortoise in them.
- [array of pictures, some of them including an upside down tortoise, or part of one]
- Explain how they make you feel.

Comment: Also put a picture of a turtle in your , just to be sure that everyone knows the difference (I dont...  )

Comment: @Bestter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Umc9ezAyJv0&feature=youtu.be&t=90

Answer (score -12):

## `Do you use natural or surrogate primary keys in your databases?`

I struggle with natural keys at work and was curious what percentage of companies across the world use what these days.

Comment: I use brass keys.

Answer (score -13):

For Employed Developers, what level has your boss made technical support and improvements on the projects, you are working?

A. Excellent
B. Good
C. Not Bad
D. Worse
E. No impact at all

Answer (score -14):

In the last survey were no voice assistant related questions. My suggestion is to add next to mobile developer as option a voice assistant developer.

As question I would like to see which Voice Assistant platforms do you know:

- Actions on Google
- Amazon Alexa
- Samsung Bixbi
- Apple Siri
- Microsoft Cortana
- Telekom Magenta
- Other

And have you developed for that platform above.

Answer (score -17):

Ask for zip code or metro area? Salaries stated for developers are skewed by Silicon Valley, by number of devs and by pay scale. Would be interesting to compare SV vs Non-SV salaries.

Comment: You mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary?

Comment: No, that is only a comparison of devs in my area. I am looking for a NOT. Something like, select average salary from devs where metro != silicon valley.

Answer (score -17):

There is already a question on gender, I would be interesting to also ask their "original physical gender" to answer a few more statistical questions I have, look for correlations, etc.

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: It allows breaking things down more deeply, to compare straight vs. non based on initial gender, etc.

Comment: For one, that's already covered in the gender option (for people who want to reveal that). This has no usefulness what so ever. And, again, why does it matter? What you were born doesn't have to mean anything years later

Comment: I believe the current question is "gender: m/f/non binary" I was looking for being able to compare more in depth.  It would be interesting to me, especially since these answer are used heavily for many of the synopsis graphs, to be able to dig deeper.  In my case the question I'd be trying to answer is "are originally X devs who are now non binary similar or different answers to 'currently X devs'".  Useful to me anyway, though perhaps a bit esoteric.  Cheers!

Comment: The current question covers male, female, non-binary, trans, possibly a couple more (I remember a couple more), and an input field labeled "Other" ("Or, in your own words:" or something). It was also multiple choice.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl there is an obvious interest from the perspective of data science. There is no need to take such a defensive stance.

Comment: @Felipe there's lots of reasons (and need) to take a defensive stance. Not everything is worth running statistics on.

Comment: That would be your personal opinion, and you have every right to express it. But you would find that position could be argued for nearly every question on the developer survey, and yet we still participate because data science helps us better understand the world around us.

I am of the personal opinion that being respectful and polite, and not making assumptions about the intent of others is also a helpful tactic in this world.

Answer (score -18):

To the topic of data science:

```
Did you implement/program a Machine Learning algorithm for your work last year?

 1. Yes
 2. No
 3. I Have never heard about Machine Learning
```

Or:

```
Did you implement a Neural Network at work in the last year?

 1. Yes

 2. No
 3. What is a neural network?
```

Comment: Reading this question I would have no idea what you mean. "I hear it" sounds like you are just asking about usage the buzzword. But then there's also "we are a complete digital company" which... I also have no idea what you mean by. You don't use paper at all? There are no physical offices? N.B.: Digitalization is definitely not a new trend.

Comment: i specified the question

Comment: I'm left even more confused than before, sadly.

Comment: Do you use ML techniques to push your business or not?

Comment: This latest revision might be a fairly interesting question if fleshed out to include particular ML technologies rather than just a yes/no question. Also given the survey is normally pretty early in the year you might want to replace 2020 with "in the past year".

Answer (score -18):

> Independently of your own preference, would you want StackOverflow to add an option of a dark theme, to SO and MSO?
>
> - Yes
> - No
>
> Note that the dark theme will be in addition to the light theme; which one used is your choice.

Considering past practices on asking questions about Stack Overflow, like having people describe it in emotional words, the answers to this question is a partial answer to how satisfied people are with SO. I have a need for dark modes, a need that SO doesn't fulfill.

It's also worth noting that there's been quite a few controversial cases about SE's attitude towards contributors to SO, lately, namely that many feel it as if SE is not interested in the thoughts of the core community. The developer survey has, as stated above, previously let people add their words of choice to a bank of words that are supposed to describe SO. This can describe if people are happy or not with SO, but it doesn't add much concrete wishes for the site.

Comment: What was the reason to downvote this? If you don't need dark mode, can't you just answer "no" in the survey?

Comment: I downvoted because this seems like a question SE would ask if they were doing research on whether to implement dark themes, and not something worth putting in the survey. SE has also explicitly stated in the past that they won't be implementing it (at least any time soon) - this, at least to me, seems misleading. If it was a general dark/light theme question, my vote would be different. [We already have that though](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389475).

Comment: @Zoe They have asked questions about how people perceive SO, before, so I'd find this on-topic.

Comment: Votes here signal agreement or disagreement with a topic. I downvoted because I disagree with putting this in the survey. That doesn't necessarily mean it's bad or off-topic - this is my opinion.

Comment: @Zoe Ehm, yeah, I know. Agreement or disagreement if it fits in the survey = on-/off-topic (in my opinion). Anyway; I must've missed that answer/suggestion you linked to.

Answer (score -21):

> What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?
>
> - WTF?
> - Blue
> - Yellow
> - African or European?
> - I refuse to answer this as it is a silly question

Inspired by Monty Python and the Holy Grail and Monty Python's Flying Circus (but not the naughty bits).

Comment: What is your quest?

Comment: Needs an option: "I don't know that!"

Answer (score -21):

```
Do You let your employee do Freelancing?

         - Yes (Why)

         - No (Why)


Do you do Freelancing with your job?

     - Yes (Why, how often?)
     - NO (Why)
```

Comment: This one's more for managers than devs tho...

Answer (score -21):

I really love the upvoted overtime question, so I would like to know other employment-rights-related questions, such as:

- Do you get health care through your employer? [Maybe this only matters in USA :( ]
- Are you in a union?
- Do you usually get paid on time?
- Have you ever been sexually harrassed on the job?
- Does your employer reimburse you for your "tools" (hardware/software/devices)?

Comment: These are interesting questions. Some companies (operating) in Norway provide private health insurance, even though Norway has free public health care. Whether or not programmers are organized in unions however, is something that there's probably already better statistics on. The 4th and 5th questions could be interesting as well.

Answer (score -21):

How about religion for demographics?

> What religion do you identify with most?
>
> - Atheism
> - Agnosticism
> - Christianity
> - Islam
> - Buddhism
> - Hinduism
> - Judaism
> - Sikhism
> - Asatru
> - Jainism
> - Church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints
> - Jehovah's Witnesses
> - Prefer not to specify
> - Other (specify)

Though I'm not sure how detailed you'd want to get with sub-groups - do you include Jehovah's Witnesses and LDS with Christianity, or as separate items? Protestants/Catholics would draw big distinctions there, but LDS/JH would claim to be Christians. How about Protestant/Catholic Christians, or sub-groups inside Islam? Etc. That gets hairy. Maybe just a text field for free entry.

Comment: Why would this matter?

Comment: @Makoto it's demographic data - I don't think it matters in terms of how well a developer would do their job, but it would be interesting to know something about the distributions among developers and whether it's different than the world at large or other fields. Kind of like everything else in the demographic section. Same as race, gender, age, etc.

Comment: Given how polarizing some of this bio-demo data has proven to be in the past, I'm not seeing the value in asking this.  I can be convinced, I'm just...not right now.

Comment: @Makoto yeah honestly I'm not really expecting to see it added. But I would be curious to see the data.

Answer (score -22):

Favorite hamburger / chicken sandwich chain?

- McDonald's
- Mos Burger
- Burger King
- KFC
- Popeyes
- Shake Shack
- Johnny Rockets
- Dairy Queen
- some local chain (Lotteria, Mom's Touch, etc.)

Comment: This seems like it may be too localised to be a useful question. For instance, as a UK resident, I've only heard of McDonald's, Burger King, and KFC so it's impossible for any of the others to be my favourite.

Comment: Hope I get to skip this; I barely eat such food, and if I do, it's in non-burger restaurants or at home. I've also never heard of any of those companies (I'm Norwegian), except McDonald's and Burger King (even fewer than @WaiHaLee).

Answer (score -23):

1. Which IDE do you prefer?

   - IntelliJ IDEA
   - Eclipse
   - NetBeans
   - Visual Studio
   - WebStorm

2. Do you prefer Vim or Emacs?

Comment: InteillJ IDEA, Visual Studio or WebStorm? What kind of developer are you aiming for?

Comment: IDE is almost always dictated by the platform you a developing on rather than preference.

Comment: That's a very strange almost always ^. I quite disagree with it. There are generally multiple choices, whatever the platform you're developping on is. Or did you mean developping *for* @DavidG?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Yes, maybe "for" is a better word. Like if I'm doing C# dev, I'll almost certainly be using Visual Studio.

Comment: The different platforms have different preference.

Comment: Many/most IDE's are cross platform enough...unless it's c# LOL

Answer (score -24):

> Does P=NP?
>
> - Yes
> - No
> - What?

Comment: Gotta add the other troll answer `IFF N==1`

Comment: @yhyrcanus or if P==0...

Answer (score -25):

What if stackoverflow adds functionality like Fiverr or Upwork only for developers?

Comment: That would be awesome!!! If I had 5 bucks for every answer... I would have surprisingly little money. Mmmh. I think I rather volunteer my time for free than being very badly paid.

Comment: Is this really meant as a question for the developer survey?

Comment: This feels like a question SE would ask if they wanted to implement it. It's not suitable for a developer survey

Comment: Way too open-ended... Or was this a feature request?

Comment: We'd all die in a hate-storm.

Answer (score -25):

What is your Single N-Back exercise level?

- 3 and lower
- 4-5
- 6-7
- 8 and higher

https://www.gwern.net/DNB-FAQ describes this exercise.

To my mind it would be very interesting to find correlation between other measures and one simple criteria.

Comment: I can ensure you that noone will be going to read a 127 page long scientific paper during a survey. Unless you can formulate it into a single question and find a way to evaluate the exercise level during the survey (I, at least, don't now my level), I see now way to ask the question.

Comment: This can be easily measured through mobile app or desktop application, and as I see, it correlates with other measures

Comment: I'm sure it can be measured. But can it easily be measured in a way that can be integrated in the survey?

Comment: Actually the answer is - depends. Upon technologies available in survey system. But I'd rather agree that not so many people would agree to this excercise. Maybe IQ details should be inserted instead. Anyway, to my mind this survey can provide so much information about developers as matched to developer's "soft skills"

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=nback&ia=web Online tests. I don't think it correlates with programming because apparently I suck at those tests.

Answer (score -28):

What is your political affiliation?

- Democrat
- Republican
- Socialist
- Libertarian
- Anarcho-Communist
- Anarcho-Capitalist
- Syndicalist
- Georgism
- Conservative
- Progressive
- Classical Liberal
- Monarchist

Comment: I think it's a very good idea to keep politics as far from SO as we can...

Comment: @Cerbrus I think some interesting correlations could be discovered. And you forgot https://politics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I did say SO, not SE.

Comment: @Cerbrus too late, SE is already used as a political platform by its owners. E.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand