# Why did Google Search Trends for Stack Overflow spike in April 2019?

Tags: discussion, google

According to [Google Search Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/), there was a significant spike in searches for Stack Overflow during the first week of April 2019.

[image: 12 month search trends for Stack Overflow]

On a larger scale, April 2019 marks the highest search interest for Stack Overflow in the past 5 years.

[image: 5 year search trends for Stack Overflow]

What happened in April 2019 to cause such a drastic spike in searches?

Comment: A wild guess but - is 1st of April responsible? Was there some external resource that linked to SO as a joke or something?

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, related queries and related topics list april fools.

Answer (score 2):

During april fools, SO changed it's whole layout to it's old original one for a few days.

With sparkly background colors and effects, comic-sans font, a guestbox and an unicorn.

It was announced on this Meta too: [Announcing the Stack Overflow Time Machine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382111/announcing-the-stack-overflow-time-machine)

It's very likely that's the cause of the search interest.